# saving custom object which contains another custom object into NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I understand how to store a custom object in NSUser Defaults but when i tried to implement saving an object with an object of different type inside it (it is called composition if i'm not mistaken) following the same steps for inner object as i did for the first one i got runtime error. Could you please minutely describe steps that i have to undertake in order to save and retrieve everything correctly

Comment: Show us what you did (your code) and we'll tell you what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All your objects should implement NSCoding protocol. NSCoding works recursively for objects that would be saved. For example, you have 2 custom classes

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {

}
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *myString;
@property(nonatomic, retain) MyAnotherClass *myAnotherClass;

@interface MyAnotherClass : NSObject {

}
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *myNumber;
```

For saving MyClass object to NSUserDefaults you need to implement NSCoding protocol to both these classes:

For first class:

```
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder{
    [encoder encodeObject:self.myString forKey:@"myString"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.myAnotherClass forKey:@"myAnotherClass"];
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder{
    self = [super init];
    if ( self != nil ) {
        self.myString = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"myString"];
        self.myAnotherClass = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"myAnotherClass"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

For second class:

```
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder{
    [encoder encodeObject:self.myNumber forKey:@"myNumber"];
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder{
    self = [super init];
    if ( self != nil ) {
        self.myNumber = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"myNumber"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Note, if your another class (MyAnotherClass above) has also *custom object* then that *custom object* should implement NSCoding as well. Even you have NSArray which implicity contains *custom objects* you should implement NSCoding for these objects.

Comment: can you please tell me in your First class i have a array with MyAnotherClass. How can i use NSCoding.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you cannot do this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19720674/8047   You need to convert to `NSData` first.