# Attempt to set a non-property-list object as an NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, encoding, nsuserdefaults

I thought I knew what was causing this error, but I can't seem to figure out what I did wrong.

Here is the full error message I am getting:

```
Attempt to set a non-property-list object (
   "<BC_Person: 0x8f3c140>"
) as an NSUserDefaults value for key personDataArray
```

I have a `Person` class that I think is conforming to the `NSCoding` protocol, where I have both of these methods in my person class:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    [coder encodeObject:self.personsName forKey:@"BCPersonsName"];
    [coder encodeObject:self.personsBills forKey:@"BCPersonsBillsArray"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.personsName = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"BCPersonsName"];
        self.personsBills = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"BCPersonsBillsArray"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

At some point in the app, the `NSString` in the `BC_PersonClass` is set, and I have a `DataSave` class that I think is handling the encoding the properties in my `BC_PersonClass`.
Here is the code I am using from the `DataSave` class:

```
- (void)savePersonArrayData:(BC_Person *)personObject
{
   // NSLog(@"name of the person %@", personObject.personsName);

    [mutableDataArray addObject:personObject];

    // set the temp array to the mutableData array
    tempMuteArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:mutableDataArray];

    // save the person object as nsData
    NSData *personEncodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:personObject];

    // first add the person object to the mutable array
    [tempMuteArray addObject:personEncodedObject];

    // NSLog(@"Objects in the array %lu", (unsigned long)mutableDataArray.count);

    // now we set that data array to the mutable array for saving
    dataArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:mutableDataArray];
    //dataArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableDataArray];

    // save the object to NS User Defaults
    NSUserDefaults *userData = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userData setObject:dataArray forKey:@"personDataArray"];
    [userData synchronize];
}
```

I hope this is enough code to give you an idea o what I am trying to do. 
Again I know my problem lie with how I am encoding my properties in my BC_Person class, I just can't seem to figure out what though I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Wonder how can we check if it is property list object or not

Comment: `that I think is conforming to the NSCoding protocol` it is super easy to add unit testing for that, and really worth it.

Comment: Best to do is to check your parameters.I found out that I was adding a string which was a number.So that's not to be used, hence was the problem.

Comment: https://elmland.blog/2018/12/17/save-load-structs-userdefaults/

Answer (score 286, accepted):

The code you posted tries to save an array of custom objects to `NSUserDefaults`. You can't do that. Implementing the `NSCoding` methods doesn't help. You can only store things like `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSString`, `NSData`, `NSNumber`, and `NSDate` in `NSUserDefaults`.

You need to convert the object to `NSData` (like you have in some of the code) and store that `NSData` in `NSUserDefaults`. You can even store an `NSArray` of `NSData` if you need to.

When you read back the array you need to unarchive the `NSData` to get back your `BC_Person` objects.

Perhaps you want this:

```
- (void)savePersonArrayData:(BC_Person *)personObject {
    [mutableDataArray addObject:personObject];

    NSMutableArray *archiveArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:mutableDataArray.count];
    for (BC_Person *personObject in mutableDataArray) { 
        NSData *personEncodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:personObject];
        [archiveArray addObject:personEncodedObject];
    }

    NSUserDefaults *userData = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userData setObject:archiveArray forKey:@"personDataArray"];
}
```

Comment: One question I have. If I wanted to add the personEncodedObject into an array and then put the array into user Data... could i just replace: [archiveArray addObject:personEncodedObject]; with a NSArray and add the addObject:personEncodedObject into that array and then save that in userData?  If you follow what I'm saying.

Comment: Huh? I think you make a typo since you want to replace a line of code with the same line of code. My code does put the array of encoded objects in the user defaults.

Comment: I guess I'm lost as I thought you could only use NSArray with userDefaults, but I see in your example you're using NSMutable array. Maybe I'm just not understanding something...

Comment: `NSMutableArray` extends `NSArray`. It's perfectly fine to pass an `NSMutableArray` to any method that expects an `NSArray`. Keep in mind that the array actually stored in `NSUserDefaults` will be immutable when you read it back.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, so then all I should have to do is set the immutable array to a mutable array so that I add more data to the array. Thank you for your answers, this was very helpful!

Comment: Be a little careful using mutable arrays. If you do something like [nsud setObject:myMutableArray forKey:@"mutableArray"];, then a few minutes later do [myMutableArray addObject:@"something"]; [nsud setObject:myMutableArray forKey:@"mutableArray"];, NSUserDefaults will go "oh! That's the same object, I already have that. No need to set it again".

Comment: @Catfish_Man Works fine with `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: NSMutableArray in general works fine. The *specific scenario* I described is not reliable.

Comment: I would use NSDictionary with my custom objects instead of nsdata

Comment: @rmaddy: This is great and correct, but what's the full list for "things like NSArray, NSDictionary..."?  Thank you!

Comment: Hey your save code totally work but how can i load array again ? because list convert to byte

Comment: When I used ur code I faced this issue 
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FKChannel encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb97a4bfc50'

Comment: Does this cost anything in performance? for example if this was running through a loop and populating a custom class object many times then changing it to NSData before adding each one to an array, would this have any greater performance issue than just passing normal data types to the array?

Answer (score 67):

It seems rather wasteful to me to run through the array and encode the objects into NSData yourself. Your error `BC_Person is a non-property-list object` is telling you that the framework doesn't know how to serialize your person object.

So all that is needed is to ensure that your person object conforms to NSCoding then you can simply convert your array of custom objects into NSData and store that to defaults. Heres a playground:

**Edit**: Writing to `NSUserDefaults` is broken on Xcode 7 so the playground will archive to data and back and print an output. The UserDefaults step is included in case its fixed at a later point

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Foundation

class Person: NSObject, NSCoding {
    let surname: String
    let firstname: String

    required init(firstname:String, surname:String) {
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.surname = surname
        super.init()
    }

    //MARK: - NSCoding -
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        surname = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("surname") as! String
        firstname = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("firstname") as! String
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(firstname, forKey: "firstname")
        aCoder.encodeObject(surname, forKey: "surname")
    }
}

//: ### Now lets define a function to convert our array to NSData

func archivePeople(people:[Person]) -> NSData {
    let archivedObject = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(people as NSArray)
    return archivedObject
}

//: ### Create some people

let people = [Person(firstname: "johnny", surname:"appleseed"),Person(firstname: "peter", surname: "mill")]

//: ### Archive our people to NSData

let peopleData = archivePeople(people)

if let unarchivedPeople = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(peopleData) as? [Person] {
    for person in unarchivedPeople {
        print("\(person.firstname), you have been unarchived")
    }
} else {
    print("Failed to unarchive people")
}

//: ### Lets try use NSUserDefaults
let UserDefaultsPeopleKey = "peoplekey"
func savePeople(people:[Person]) {
    let archivedObject = archivePeople(people)
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setObject(archivedObject, forKey: UserDefaultsPeopleKey)
    defaults.synchronize()
}

func retrievePeople() -> [Person]? {
    if let unarchivedObject = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(UserDefaultsPeopleKey) as? NSData {
        return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(unarchivedObject) as? [Person]
    }
    return nil
}

if let retrievedPeople = retrievePeople() {
    for person in retrievedPeople {
        print("\(person.firstname), you have been unarchived")
    }
} else {
    print("Writing to UserDefaults is still broken in playgrounds")
}
```

And Voila, you have stored an array of custom objects into NSUserDefaults

Comment: This answer is solid! I had my objects conforming with NSCoder, but I forgot about the array they where stored in. Thanks, saved me many hours!

Comment: @Daniel, I just pasted your code as is into playground xcode 7.3 and it is giving an error on "let retrievedPeople: [Person] = retrievePeople()!" -> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0). What adjustments do I need to make? Thanks

Comment: @rockhammer looks like NSUserDefaults doesn't work in Playgrounds since Xcode 7:( will update shortly

Comment: @Daniel, no problem. I went ahead and inserted your code into my project and it works like a charm! My object class has an NSDate in addition to 3 String types. I just needed to substitute NSDate for String in the decode func. Thanks

Comment: For Swift3: ```func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)```

Comment: @DanielGalasko Can you please also put Delete Functionality from User Defaults and give example??

Comment: Hi @ParthBarot that is not really the original question unless I misinterpreted. There is a very clear API for removing objects if you check the documentation. Take a look here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults

If it is still unclear, ask a new question :)

Answer (score 52):

To save:

```
NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:yourObject];
[currentDefaults setObject:data forKey:@"yourKeyName"];
```

To Get:

```
NSData *data = [currentDefaults objectForKey:@"yourKeyName"];
yourObjectType * token = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

For Remove

```
[currentDefaults removeObjectForKey:@"yourKeyName"];
```

Answer (score 35):

## Swift 3 Solution

### Simple utility class

```
class ArchiveUtil {

    private static let PeopleKey = "PeopleKey"

    private static func archivePeople(people : [Human]) -> NSData {

        return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: people as NSArray) as NSData
    }

    static func loadPeople() -> [Human]? {

        if let unarchivedObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: PeopleKey) as? Data {

            return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: unarchivedObject as Data) as? [Human]
        }

        return nil
    }

    static func savePeople(people : [Human]?) {

        let archivedObject = archivePeople(people: people!)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(archivedObject, forKey: PeopleKey)
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }

}
```

### Model Class

```
class Human: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var name:String?
    var age:Int?

    required init(n:String, a:Int) {

        name = n
        age = a
    }


    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as? String
        age = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "age")
    }


    public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {

        aCoder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
        aCoder.encode(age, forKey: "age")

    }
}
```

### How to call

```
var people = [Human]()

people.append(Human(n: "Sazzad", a: 21))
people.append(Human(n: "Hissain", a: 22))
people.append(Human(n: "Khan", a: 23))

ArchiveUtil.savePeople(people: people)

let others = ArchiveUtil.loadPeople()

for human in others! {

    print("name = \(human.name!), age = \(human.age!)")
}
```

Comment: Nice! :D the best swift Adaptation +1

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize ... "this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used." LOL ... someone at apple is not a team player.

Answer (score 15):

### Swift- 4 Xcode 9.1

**try this code**

**you can not store mapper in NSUserDefault, you can only store NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary.**

```
let myData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: myJson)
UserDefaults.standard.set(myData, forKey: "userJson")

let recovedUserJsonData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "userJson")
let recovedUserJson = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: recovedUserJsonData)
```

Comment: Thank-you for this. NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject:) has been deprecated in iOS12 to a new method that throws an error. Perhaps an update to your code? :)

Answer (score 14):

**Swift** with `@propertyWrapper`

Save `Codable` object to `UserDefault`

```
@propertyWrapper
    struct UserDefault<T: Codable> {
        let key: String
        let defaultValue: T

        init(_ key: String, defaultValue: T) {
            self.key = key
            self.defaultValue = defaultValue
        }

        var wrappedValue: T {
            get {

                if let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as? Data,
                    let user = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data) {
                    return user

                }

                return  defaultValue
            }
            set {
                if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(newValue) {
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: key)
                }
            }
        }
    }




enum GlobalSettings {

    @UserDefault("user", defaultValue: User(name:"",pass:"")) static var user: User
}
```

Example User model confirm Codable

```
struct User:Codable {
    let name:String
    let pass:String
}
```

**How to use it**

```
//Set value 
 GlobalSettings.user = User(name: "Ahmed", pass: "Ahmed")

//GetValue
print(GlobalSettings.user)
```

Comment: This is the best MODERN ANSWER. 

Stacker, use this answer is is genuinely scaleable.

Answer (score 11):

First off, rmaddy's answer (above) is right: implementing `NSCoding` doesn't help. However, you need to implement `NSCoding` to use `NSKeyedArchiver` and all that, so it's just one more step... converting via `NSData`.

Example methods

```
- (NSUserDefaults *) defaults {
    return [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
}

- (void) persistObj:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key {
    [self.defaults setObject:value  forKey:key];
    [self.defaults synchronize];
}

- (void) persistObjAsData:(id)encodableObject forKey:(NSString *)key {
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:encodableObject];
    [self persistObj:data forKey:key];
}    

- (id) objectFromDataWithKey:(NSString*)key {
    NSData *data = [self.defaults objectForKey:key];
    return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
}
```

So you can wrap your `NSCoding` objects in an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` or whatever...

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem trying save a dictionary to `NSUserDefaults`. It turns out it wouldn't save because it contained `NSNull` values. So I just copied the dictionary into a mutable dictionary removed the nulls then saved to `NSUserDefaults`

```
NSMutableDictionary* dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dictionary_trying_to_save];
[dictionary removeObjectForKey:@"NullKey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dictionary forKey:@"key"];
```

In this case I knew which keys might be `NSNull` values.

Answer (score 6):

> Swift 5: The **Codable** protocol can be used instead of **NSKeyedArchiever**.

```
struct User: Codable {
    let id: String
    let mail: String
    let fullName: String
}
```

The **Pref** struct is custom wrapper around the UserDefaults standard object.

```
struct Pref {
    static let keyUser = "Pref.User"
    static var user: User? {
        get {
            if let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: keyUser) as? Data {
                do {
                    return try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)
                } catch {
                    print("Error while decoding user data")
                }
            }
            return nil
        }
        set {
            if let newValue = newValue {
                do {
                    let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(newValue)
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: keyUser)
                } catch {
                    print("Error while encoding user data")
                }
            } else {
                UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: keyUser)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So you can use it this way:

```
Pref.user?.name = "John"

if let user = Pref.user {...
```

Comment: `if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: keyUser) {` and Btw casting from `User` to `User` is pointless just `return try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)`

Answer (score 5):

> https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults
>
> A default object must be a property list—that is, an instance of (or for collections, a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary.
>
> If you want to store any other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an instance of NSData. For more details, see Preferences and Settings Programming Guide.

Answer (score 4):

***Swift  5*** Very Easy way

```
//MARK:- First you need to encoded your arr or what ever object you want to save in UserDefaults
//in my case i want to save Picture (NMutableArray) in the User Defaults in
//in this array some objects are UIImage & Strings

//first i have to encoded the NMutableArray 
let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: yourArrayName)
//MARK:- Array save in UserDefaults
defaults.set(encodedData, forKey: "YourKeyName")

//MARK:- When you want to retreive data from UserDefaults
let decoded  = defaults.object(forKey: "YourKeyName") as! Data
yourArrayName = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded) as! NSMutableArray

//MARK: Enjoy this arrry "yourArrayName"
```

Comment: this is only for codable struct

Comment: I get:  'archivedData(withRootObject:)' was deprecated in macOS 10.14: Use +archivedDataWithRootObject:requiringSecureCoding:error: instead

Comment: This is not working! Getting the above warning!

Comment: let me check it again and i will update it soon

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this and eventually figured out it was because I was trying to use `NSNumber` as dictionary keys, and property lists only allow strings as keys. The documentation for [`setObject:forKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults/1414067-setobject) doesn't mention this limitation, but the [About Property Lists](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH3-54303) page that it links to does:

> By convention, each Cocoa and Core Foundation object listed in Table 2-1 is called a property-list object. Conceptually, you can think of “property list” as being an abstract superclass of all these classes. If you receive a property list object from some method or function, you know that it must be an instance of one of these types, but a priori you may not know which type. If a property-list object is a container (that is, an array or dictionary), all objects contained within it must also be property-list objects. If an array or dictionary contains objects that are not property-list objects, then you cannot save and restore the hierarchy of data using the various property-list methods and functions. And although NSDictionary and CFDictionary objects allow their keys to be objects of any type, **if the keys are not string objects, the collections are not property-list objects.**

(Emphasis mine)