# Saving custom class object's array in NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I created a custom class to display in a TableView, I read a custom class object's array in TableView. Now, when I close the app I lose my date. I want to save that data permanently. But when I try to do so, I get the following error:

```
Attempt to set a non-property-list object as an NSUserDefaults
```

My code is:

```
@implementation CAChallangeListViewController
- (void)loadInitialData{
    self.challangeItems = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"challanges"];
}
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.challangeItems forKey:@"challanges"];
}
```

Here, the self. Challange items is a NSMutable array which contains objects of type CAChallange which is a custom class with following interface.

```
@interface CAChallange : NSObject
    @property NSString *itemName;
    @property BOOL *completed;
    @property (readonly) NSDate *creationDate;
@end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Attempt to set a non-property-list object as an NSUserDefaults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720611/attempt-to-set-a-non-property-list-object-as-an-nsuserdefaults)

Comment: conform to the NSCoding protocol and save it as NSData

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily accomplish what you are doing by converting your object into a standard dictionary (and back when you need to read it).

```
NSMutableArray *itemsToSave = [NSMutableArray array];
for (CAChallange *ch in myTableItems) {
   [itemsToSave addObject:@{ @"itemName"     : ch.itemName,
                             @"completed"    : @(ch.completed),
                             @"creationDate" : ch.creationDate }];
}
```

Comment: You are looping in an empty array in the example

Comment: Good catch thanks. I needed another variable that describes the original data source.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSKeyedArchiver` to create an `NSData` representation of your object. Your class will need to conform to the `NSCoding` protocol, which can be a bit tedious, but the [AutoCoding](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AutoCoding) category can do the work for you. After adding that to your project, you can easily serialize your objects like this:

```
id customObject = // Your object to persist
NSData *customObjectData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:customObject];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:customObjectData forKey:@"PersistenDataKey"];
```

And deserialize it like this:

```
NSData *customObjectData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"PersistenDataKey"];
id customObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:customObjectData];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `CAChallange` object has a pointer to a BOOL which is not a suitable type for a plist:-

```
 @property BOOL *completed
```

This is probably causing the error. You cannot store raw pointers in a plist.

Comment: I think it is the `CAChallange` type the compiler objects to. Booleans are possible as NSUserDefaults.