# how to save and read array of array in NSUserdefaults in swift?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, xcode6

I need create an array to add objects with this format like a dictionary in Swift : ["key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"]

When I try to save it with `NSUserDefaults` all is correct, but when read `NSUserDefaults` with the key this crashes. What type of data does my var obj need?

```
let def = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var key = "keySave"
var element: AnyObject!

var array1: [AnyObject!] = []
array1.append(["key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"])
array1.append(["key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"])

//save
var savestring : [AnyObject!]
savestring = array1
var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject(savestring, forKey: key)
defaults.synchronize()

//read
var obj: [AnyObject!] = []
if(obj != nil){
    print("size: ")
    print(obj.count) //vary long value confused..
    element = obj[0]  //crash
    print(element.objectForKey("key1"))
}
```

Comment: It looks like NSUserDefaults can handle String but not Array and Dictionary, working only for the NS* types describing the docs. So this looks like a bug in Swift.

Comment: To go a little bit beyond what @Zaph says, I tested with [String] and it's not working, but it is working with [NSString]. Check my answer.

Answer (score 257, accepted):

The question reads "array of array" but I think most people probably come here just wanting to know how to save an array to `UserDefaults`. For those people I will add a few common examples.

## String array

Save array

```
let array = ["horse", "cow", "camel", "sheep", "goat"]

let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(array, forKey: "SavedStringArray")
```

Retrieve array

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let myarray = defaults.stringArray(forKey: "SavedStringArray") ?? [String]()
```

## Int array

Save array

```
let array = [15, 33, 36, 723, 77, 4]

let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(array, forKey: "SavedIntArray")
```

Retrieve array

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let array = defaults.array(forKey: "SavedIntArray")  as? [Int] ?? [Int]()
```

## Bool array

Save array

```
let array = [true, true, false, true, false]

let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(array, forKey: "SavedBoolArray")
```

Retrieve array

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let array = defaults.array(forKey: "SavedBoolArray")  as? [Bool] ?? [Bool]()
```

## Date array

Save array

```
let array = [Date(), Date(), Date(), Date()]

let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(array, forKey: "SavedDateArray")
```

Retrieve array

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let array = defaults.array(forKey: "SavedDateArray")  as? [Date] ?? [Date]()
```

## Object array

Custom objects (and consequently arrays of objects) take a little more work to save to `UserDefaults`. See the following links for how to do it.

- [Save custom objects into NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986957/save-custom-objects-into-nsuserdefaults)
- [Docs for saving color to UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DrawColor/Tasks/StoringNSColorInDefaults.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001693)
- [Attempt to set a non-property-list object as an NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720611/attempt-to-set-a-non-property-list-object-as-an-nsuserdefaults)

## Notes

- The nil coalescing operator (`??`) allows you to return the saved array or an empty array without crashing. It means that if the object returns nil, then the value following the `??` operator will be used instead.
- As you can see, the basic setup was the same for `Int`, `Bool`, and `Date`. I also tested it with `Double`. As far as I know, anything that you can save in a property list will work like this.

Answer (score 16):

Just to add on to what @Zaph says in the comments.

I have the same problem as you, as to know, the array of `String` is not saved. Even though Apple bridges types such as String and NSString, I wasn't able to save an array of `[String]` neither of `[AnyObject]`.

However an array of `[NSString]` works for me.

So your code could look like that :

```
var key = "keySave"

var array1: [NSString] = [NSString]()
array1.append("value 1")
array1.append("value 2")

//save
var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject(array1, forKey: key)
defaults.synchronize()

//read
if let testArray : AnyObject? = defaults.objectForKey(key) {
    var readArray : [NSString] = testArray! as [NSString]
}
```

Note that I created an array of NSString and not a dictionary. I didn't check if it works with a dictionary, but probably you will have to define the things as `[NSString : NSString]` to have it working.

**EDIT**

Re-reading your question and your title, you are talking of `array of array`. I think that as long as you stay with `NSString`, an array of array will work. However, if you think my answer is irrelevant, just let me know in the comments and I will remove it.

Answer (score 11):

Here is an example of reading and writing a list of objects of type `SNStock` that implements `NSCoding` - we have an accessor for the entire list, `watchlist`, and two methods to add and remove objects, that is `addStock(stock: SNStock)` and `removeStock(stock: SNStock)`.

```
import Foundation

class DWWatchlistController {

  private let kNSUserDefaultsWatchlistKey: String = "dw_watchlist_key"

  private let userDefaults: NSUserDefaults

  private(set) var watchlist:[SNStock] {

    get {
      if let watchlistData : AnyObject = userDefaults.objectForKey(kNSUserDefaultsWatchlistKey) {
        if let watchlist : AnyObject = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(watchlistData as! NSData) {
          return watchlist as! [SNStock]
        }
      }
      return []
    }

    set(watchlist) {
      let watchlistData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(watchlist)
      userDefaults.setObject(watchlistData, forKey: kNSUserDefaultsWatchlistKey)
      userDefaults.synchronize()
    }
  }

  init() {
    userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
  }

  func addStock(stock: SNStock) {
    var watchlist = self.watchlist
    watchlist.append(stock)
    self.watchlist = watchlist
  }

  func removeStock(stock: SNStock) {
    var watchlist = self.watchlist
    if let index = find(watchlist, stock) {
      watchlist.removeAtIndex(index)
      self.watchlist = watchlist
    }
  }

}
```

Remember that **your object needs to implement `NSCoding`** or else the encoding won't work. Here is what `SNStock` looks like:

```
import Foundation

class SNStock: NSObject, NSCoding
{
  let ticker: NSString
  let name: NSString

  init(ticker: NSString, name: NSString)
  {
    self.ticker = ticker
    self.name = name
  }

  //MARK: NSCoding

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.ticker = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("ticker") as! NSString
    self.name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as! NSString
  }

  func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(ticker, forKey: "ticker")
    aCoder.encodeObject(name, forKey: "name")
  }

  //MARK: NSObjectProtocol

  override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    if let object = object as? SNStock {
      return self.ticker == object.ticker &&
        self.name == object.name
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }

  override var hash: Int {
    return ticker.hashValue
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4.0**

**Store:**

```
let arrayFruit = ["Apple","Banana","Orange","Grapes","Watermelon"]    

 //store in user default
 UserDefaults.standard.set(arrayFruit, forKey: "arrayFruit")
```

**Fetch:**

```
if let arr = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "arrayFruit") as? [String]{
        print(arr)
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is:

```
var array : [String] = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard
// set
userDefault.set(array, forKey: "array")
// retrieve 
if let fetchArray = userDefault.array(forKey: "array") as? [String] {
    // code 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

To get the data from the UserDefaults.

```
var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var dict : NSDictionary = ["key":"value"]
var array1: NSArray = dict.allValues // Create a dictionary and assign that to this array
defaults.setObject(array1, forkey : "MyKey")

var myarray : NSArray = defaults.objectForKey("MyKey") as NSArray
println(myarray)
```

Comment: I add var dict: [AnyObject!] = []   and   var array1: NSArray = dict   but this is empty, How can make this correctly?

Comment: @AlvinVarghese Actually try the code. There is a typo and even when that is fixed the only thing saved is an array with one entry: "value".

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with **Swift 5+** you have to use `UserDefaults.standard.setValue(value, forKey: key)` and to get saved data you have to use `UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: key)`.