# Save custom objects into NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm having a news `ViewController` and a `TeamViewController`. The `TeamViewController` contain a tableView of teamObjects which when selected is added into array. I want to add this array into `NSUserDefaults` so i can access them from the `NewsController` which contain a url request where the teamObjects is needed. However i keep getting:

> 'Attempt to insert non-property list object (
>         ""
>      ) for key teams'

I'm open for other suggestions if there is better ways than storing it in `NSUserDefaults`

`didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)


    let team = self.teamArray[indexPath.row] as Team
    var removed = false

    for (index, value) in enumerate(self.teamSelected) {
        if (value == team) {
            self.teamSelected.removeAtIndex(index)
            removed = true
        }
    }

    if (!removed) {
        self.teamSelected.append(team)
    }

    var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    userDefaults.setValue(self.teamSelected, forKey: "teams")
    userDefaults.synchronize()

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

My object

```
class Team: NSObject{
    var id: Int!
    var name: NSString!
    var shortname: NSString!


    init(id: Int, name:NSString, shortname: NSString) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.shortname = shortname

    }

}
```

Answer (score 246, accepted):

Actually, you will need to archive the custom object into `NSData` then save it to user defaults and retrieve it from user defaults and unarchive it again.
You can archive it like this

```
let teams = [Team(id: 1, name: "team1", shortname: "t1"), Team(id: 2, name: "team2", shortname: "t2")]

var userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
let encodedData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: teams)
userDefaults.set(encodedData, forKey: "teams")
```

and unarchive it like this

```
let decoded  = userDefaults.data(forKey: "teams")
let decodedTeams = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded) as! [Team]
```

But if you just did that you will get

```
.Team encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

You will have to make Team conform to NSCoding just like this

```
class Team: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var shortname: String


    init(id: Int, name: String, shortname: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.shortname = shortname

    }

    required convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let id = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "id")
        let name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as! String
        let shortname = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "shortname") as! String
        self.init(id: id, name: name, shortname: shortname)
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(id, forKey: "id")
        aCoder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
        aCoder.encode(shortname, forKey: "shortname")
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you deal with the error caused by this line `let decodedTeams = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(decoded) as! [Team]` (the error being `Can throw but the error is not handled`)?

Comment: @afkatja Check the updated code-- it should work now :)

Comment: Thank you in particular for including decodeInteger in this example, that had me noticed that type casting really counts in this function.

Comment: can we save UIImage with this method?

Comment: You have to convert it to NSData. You can't save UIImage directly.

Comment: "required convenience init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)" this method is not getting called for me, any help appreciated

Comment: I wonder if this can be done with struct?

Comment: what if team had a custom object inside it , do we need to add NSCoding to that custom object's class also??

Answer (score 11):

You can try **NSKeyedUnarchiver**, like below

Here i stored UIColor Object in UserDefault You can change it with your object

```
 NSData *colorData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:color];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:colorData forKey:@"myColor"];
```

and to retrive that

```
NSData *colorData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myColor"];
UIColor *color = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:colorData];
```

**Note : This is Objective C but I hope you can covert this in Swift**

Hope this solve your problem

---

**Update : Swift 5**

Archive in Swift

```
do{
    let colorAsData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: UIColor.red, requiringSecureCoding: true)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(colorAsData, forKey: "myColor")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}catch (let error){ 
    #if DEBUG
        print("Failed to convert UIColor to Data : \(error.localizedDescription)")
    #endif
}
```

Unarchive in Swift

```
do{
    if let colorAsData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "myColor") as? Data{
        if let color = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClasses: [UIColor.self], from: colorAsData){
            // Use Color
        }
    }
}catch (let error){
    #if DEBUG
        print("Failed to convert UIColor to Data : \(error.localizedDescription)")
    #endif
}
```

Comment: due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Striky.Team encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector

Comment: That's because you need to conform to NSCoding protocol