# set UserDefaultValue Swift 3 Error

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

1. I have a model
2. I want to pass value of my model to other class
3. I set in userDefault but get error "thread 1 signal sigabrt"

   ```
   Alamofire.request("http://mylink.com/login", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<LoginResponse>)
       in
       let loginResponse: AnyObject = response.result.value!


       UserDefaults.standard.setValue(loginResponse, forKey: "resultLogin")



   }
   ```

So i want to ask how to set my model value to user default

Comment: Check your loginResponse. May be your model contain nil value for any key. I have same issue and found that value of one of my key is nil.

Comment: Which exact line of code causes the error?

Comment: @rmaddy UserDefaults.standard.setValue(loginResponse, forKey: "resultLogin")

Comment: Though not related to your crash, do not use `setValue(forKey:)`. Use `set(forKey:)`. And you can only store specific data types in `UserDefaults`. Please read the documentation for `UserDefaults` to see the value types. Hint: `AnyObject` is not one of the valid types.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986957/save-custom-objects-into-nsuserdefaults

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your login response to data and then save to `UserDefaults`. Otherwise you can also use `NSKeyedArchiever` after converting the response into `Data`. Refer to this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26469457/saving-custom-swift-class-with-nscoding-to-userdefaults)

Answer (score 0):

To store a value or object in User default, that value or object must be `NSCoding` complaint. Here you are setting value of type AnyObject in user default.
To make this work,create a model and implement the NSCoding.