# Store custom class in UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm trying to store a custom class in user defaults but throughs an exception

> terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

My class is as follows: **Transactions**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON
class Transactions: NSObject,NSCoding {
    var transOBJ = [JSON]()
    init(transOBJ:[JSON]) {
        self.transOBJ = transOBJ
    }
    required convenience init(coder aDecoder:NSCoder) {
        let obj = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "OBJ") as! [JSON]
        self.init(transOBJ: obj)
    }
    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(transOBJ, forKey: "OBJ")
    }
}
```

The exception is throwing on **aCoder.encode(transOBJ, forKey: "OBJ")**

The code for saving in user defaults is:

```
let trans = [Transactions(transOBJ: self.transactionObjs)]
var userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
let encodedData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: trans)
userDefaults.set(encodedData, forKey: "transactions")
userDefaults.synchronize()
```

**Update 1**

I am calling the user defaults inside the Alamofire request function. Then it is giving an error
But when I call it outside Alamofire request function, then it runs just fine. What should I do?
I want to save it inside the success of alamofire but can't do it

Comment: Please look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315948/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-nsuserdefaults

Comment: I have already tried different codes from stack overflow but didn't help

Comment: I used the code from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986957/save-custom-objects-into-nsuserdefaults

Comment: try this http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/16205-saving-class-nsuserdefaults.html

Comment: probably `JSON` also need to conform `NSCoding`, just `Transactions` that does isnt enough

Comment: @Tj3n yes, I think you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [Tj3n](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5230311/tj3n). JSON also need to conform NSCoding. Just Transactions isn't enough. I created different variables for string and integers in the Transactions NSObject, extracted data from JSON, stored extracted data in the variables declared and then encoded and decoded them accordingly. It worked.

If there is another way, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code with your code then remove app and run again.

```
  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {           
     transOBJ = = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "OBJ") as! [JSON]
 }
```

Comment: required convenience init(coder aDecoder:NSCoder) {
        let obj = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "OBJ") as! [JSON]
        self.init(transOBJ: obj)
    } this one.

Comment: did you remove app ?

Comment: yes. And now I don't think its about my functions. It's more about where I'm calling it. Read my update 1.