# UserDefaults Custom Object of Custom Objects

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, custom-object

Part of my settings I want to save with UserDefaults.

I already found this solution here:
[Save custom objects into NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986957/save-custom-objects-into-nsuserdefaults)

But I could not figure out how to save if I have custom objects in a custom object.

My classes look like this:

```
class ConfigLabelMainList: NSObject, NSCoding {


    var labelMiddleFirst: StatsIntervalModel
    var labelMiddleSecond: StatsIntervalModel
    var labelMiddleThird: StatsIntervalModel
    var labelRightFirst: StatsIntervalModel
    var labelRightSecond: StatsIntervalModel

    init(labelMiddleFirst: StatsIntervalModel, labelMiddleSecond: StatsIntervalModel, labelMiddleThird: StatsIntervalModel, labelRightFirst: StatsIntervalModel, labelRightSecond: StatsIntervalModel) {
        self.labelMiddleFirst = labelMiddleFirst
        self.labelMiddleSecond = labelMiddleSecond
        self.labelMiddleThird = labelMiddleThird
        self.labelRightFirst = labelRightFirst
        self.labelRightSecond = labelRightSecond
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {

    }

    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    }
}


class StatsIntervalModel: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var stat: String
    var interval: String

    init(stat: String, interval: String) {
        self.stat = stat
        self.interval = interval
    }

    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let stat = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "stat") as! String
        let interval = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "interval") as! String
        self.init(stat: stat, interval: interval)
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(stat, forKey: "stat")
        aCoder.encode(interval, forKey: "interval")
    }

}
```

How would a solution look like?

Comment: There's no difference. Simply encode and decode the properties of `ConfigLabelMainList` just like you did in `StatsIntervalModel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add given code in your class `ConfigLabelMainList`

```
required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    let midFirst = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "midFirst") as! StatsIntervalModel
    let midSecond = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "midSecond") as! StatsIntervalModel
    let midThird = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "midThird") as! StatsIntervalModel
    let rightFirst = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "rightFirst") as! StatsIntervalModel
    let rightSecond = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "rightSecond") as! StatsIntervalModel

    self.init(labelMiddleFirst: midFirst, labelMiddleSecond: midSecond, labelMiddleThird: midThird, labelRightFirst: rightFirst, labelRightSecond: rightSecond)
}

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(labelMiddleFirst, forKey: "midFirst")
    aCoder.encode(labelMiddleSecond, forKey: "midSecond")
    aCoder.encode(labelMiddleThird, forKey: "midThird")
    aCoder.encode(labelRightFirst, forKey: "rightFirst")
    aCoder.encode(labelRightSecond, forKey: "rightSecond")
}
```

Now simply archive data and save it in defaults.

Comment: Thanks, this helped!