# How to append data to decodedData in Swift

Tags: json, swift, class

I followed this tutorial, [Save custom objects into NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986957/save-custom-objects-into-nsuserdefaults) to figure out how to save data with classes. My problem is that I need to update this data without overriding the old data. I am currently trying

```
let data = [ToDo(name: cardTitle.text!, length: 7, startDate: Date(), itemArray: subarray)]
let newData = decodedData.append(data)
let encodedData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: newData)

defaults.set(encodedData, forKey: "data")
defaults.synchronize()
```

but this returns an error because trying to append `data` to `decodeData` returns `()` and I have no idea how to fix it. The only thing that works is

```
let data = [decodeData[0], ToDo(name: cardTitle.text!, length: 7, startDate: Date(), itemArray: subarray)]
```

but this won't work because I need to use more than just the data at index 0.

Has anyone run into this before? Any thoughts?

Comment: Read the data, unarchive it, append the ToDo, archive it, save the data.

Comment: What's the difference between that and what I'm doing?

Comment: `append` hasn't a return value: `decodedData.append(data)` `let encodedData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: decodedData)`

Comment: OH thank you! I was used to python where u didn't want to edit the original array, thank you so much!

Comment: Unrelated but get rid of that unnecessary call to `synchronize`.