# UserDefaults.standard.object(key) always nil

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

In my case `UserDefaults.standard.object()` always returns nil.
I don't understand **why**. Please, help. I use swift 4.2 and Xcode 9.x.
My project has multiple files: swift and objC. If I set value from objC code (NSUserDefaults...), then all works fine. Value exist.

My ***class B*** at Swift-file:

```
import Foundation
@objc class Preferences : NSObject{

    /**
     Сохранение в локальном хранилище данных
     :param: key ключ (название параметра
     :param: value значение - любой тип данных
     */
    public static func saveValue (key:String, value:Any) -> (){
        UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: key)
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }

    /**
     Получить данные из локального хранилища
     :param: key ключ (название параметра)
     :returns: Any значение - любой тип данных
     */
    public static func getValue (key:String) -> (Any?){
        let val = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key)
        return val // ------- always NIL
//        if let type1 = val as? String{
//            return type1
//        }else if let type2 = val as? Int{
//            return type2
//        }else if let type3 = val as? Double{
//            return type3
//        }else{
//            return val;
//        }
    }
}
```

From objC class I calling first swift-func.

objC (check values):

```
if (![[Preferences getValueWithKey:@"surname_"] isEqualToString:@""]){
    [surnameF setText:[Preferences getValueWithKey:@"surname_"]];
    [nameF setText:[Preferences getValueWithKey:@"name_"]];
    [patronymicF setText:[Preferences getValueWithKey:@"patronymic_"]];
}
```

objC (set values by calling swift-class):

```
[DataManager saveDataWithSurname:surname name:name patronymic:patronymic];
```

***Class A*** at Swift-file:

```
@objc class DataManager : NSObject{

public static func saveData(surname: String, name: String, patronymic: String){
    //Сохранить локально
    Preferences.saveValue(key: surname, value1: "surname_")
    Preferences.saveValue(key: name, value1: "name_")
    Preferences.saveValue(key: patronymic, value1: "patronymic_")

    let sCommand = SimpleCommand()
    sCommand.command = "setUserData"
    var userData = [String:String]()
    userData["user_surname"] = surname
    userData["user_name"] = name
    userData["user_patronymic"] = patronymic
    sCommand.params["userData"] = userData

    NetHelper.sendJSONPureRequest(
        sCommand: sCommand,
        onSuccess: { (sAnswer) in
            EasyDialog.showAlert(title: "Уведомление", message: sAnswer.messageText!)
    }) { (errMsg) in
        EasyDialog.showAlert(title: "Ошибка", message: errMsg)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake:

```
public static func saveData(surname: String, name: String, patronymic: String){
    //Сохранить локально
    Preferences.saveValue(key: surname, value1: "surname_")
    Preferences.saveValue(key: name, value1: "name_")
    Preferences.saveValue(key: patronymic, value1: "patronymic_")
```

Key <-> Value. :)

Answer (score 0):

As the discussion of `func set(_ value: Any?, forKey defaultName: String)`:

> The value parameter can be only property list objects: NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. For NSArray and NSDictionary objects, their contents must be property list objects.

So a default object must be a property list - that is, an instance of (or for collections, a combination of instances of) `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary`. If you want to store any other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an instance of `NSData`.

Try the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986957/save-custom-objects-into-nsuserdefaults).

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I know about this object's list :) A just try to save simple string :)

Comment: So use `string(forKey:)` instead

Comment: It's first what I already try, no results. I think it's happens because I call swift-code from objC's code

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 Very Easy Way

[Attempt to set a non-property-list object as an NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720611/attempt-to-set-a-non-property-list-object-as-an-nsuserdefaults/56625605#56625605)

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720611/attempt-to-set-a-non-property-list-object-as-an-nsuserdefaults/56625605#56625605
```

Answer (score -1):

You should return simple object instead of closure.
Also,`synchronize` will be deprecated and you can remove it.

Try this fixed code.

```
public static func saveValue (key: String, value: Any) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: key)
}

public static func getValue (key:String) -> Any? {
    let val = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key)
    return val
}
```

Comment: OP is not returning a closure. He is returning a single element tuple, which basically means he is returning an object of that type.

Comment: I get "nil" already on line `let val = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key)`. And function returns single object. Thanks for answer!

Comment: How you set this? I just checked code with strings and works good, could you provide an example of usage?

Comment: 5 minutes ago I was try to save value from another class and all saves fine. So, I have ***class A*** with `public static func saveFullData` which calls static func from ***class B*** (`public static func saveValue (key:String, value:Any) -> ()`) where I try to save value at UserDefaults. And I can't save it in ***class B***

Comment: But I already try to change funcs from ***class B*** to non-static and no results. Maybe it's not working because I call func of ***class A*** from objC code and after that this func call ***class B***' funcs?