# Unable to store an array of custom objects in UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom object called **Badge** and I have an array of **Badges** ([Badge]) that I want to store in UserDefaults.  I believe I may be doing it incorrectly. I am able to get my code to build but I get the following error on start inside `getBadges()` : `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**.  Can someone help`. I have tried the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986957/save-custom-objects-into-nsuserdefaults) but had no luck.

```
//
//  Badge.swift
//

import Foundation

class Badge: NSObject {
    var name: String
    var info: String
    var score: Float?
    
    init(name: String, info: String, score: Float?) {
        self.name = name
        self.info = info
        self.score = score
    }
    
    static func ==(lhs: Badge, rhs: Badge) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name
    }
    
    func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(self.name, forKey: "name")
        coder.encode(self.info, forKey: "info")
    }
}
```

```
//
//  BadgeFactory.swift
//

import Foundation

class BadgeFactory {
    let defaults: UserDefaults
    var badges: [Badge] = []
    var userBadges: [Badge] = []
    static let b = "Badges"
    
    init() {
        
        self.defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        self.userBadges = self.getBadges()

    }
    
    func addBadges(score: Float) -> [Badge]
    {
        var new_badges: [Badge] = []
        
        for badge in self.badges {
            if (!self.checkIfUserHasBadge(badge: badge) && badge.score != nil && score >= badge.score!) {
                new_badges.append(badge)
                self.userBadges.append(badge)
            }
        }
        
        self.defaults.set(self.userBadges, forKey: BadgeFactory.b)
        
        return new_badges
    }
    
    func checkIfUserHasBadge(badge: Badge) -> Bool
    {
        if self.badges.contains(badge) {
            return true
        }
        else {
            return false
        }
    }
    
    func getBadges() -> [Badge] {
        return self.defaults.array(forKey: BadgeFactory.b) as! [Badge]
    }
    
    func loadDefaultBadges() {
        // Score badges.
        self.badges.append(Badge(name: "Badge1", info: "My cool badge", score: 80))
        self.badges.append(Badge(name: "Badge2", info: "My second cool badge", score: 90))
    }
        
}
```

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        var bf = BadgeFactory()
        bf.getBadges()
        bf.addBadges(score: 85)
    }

}
```

Comment: getBadges() is called twice before addBadges(). First in the BadgeFactory.init() and then in the ViewControllers.viewDidLoad().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this error is located in your `getBadges()` function:

```
func getBadges() -> [Badge] {
    return self.defaults.array(forKey: BadgeFactory.b) as! [Badge]
}
```

With `as!` you are implicitly unwrapping the array you expect. But as long as you didn't write data to this userDefaults key, `array(forKey:)` will always return `nil`!
For this reason, you need to use safe unwrapping here, for example like so:
`return self.defaults.array(forKey: BadgeFactory.b) as? [Badge] ?? []`.

---

But that's not the only problem. Like you already stumbled about, you still need to implement the solution of the thread you posted. Custom NSObjects cannot be stored in Defaults without encoding.
You need to implement the `NSCoding protocol` in your `Badge` class (`init(coder:)` is missing) and use an Unarchiver for reading, along with an Archiver for writing your data to defaults.

So your code should look something like this:

```
class Badge: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var name: String
    var info: String
    var score: Float?
    
    init(name: String, info: String, score: Float?) {
        self.name = name
        self.info = info
        self.score = score
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        self.name = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as! String
        self.info = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "info") as! String
        self.score = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "score") as? Float
    }
    
    static func ==(lhs: Badge, rhs: Badge) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name
    }
    
    func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(self.name, forKey: "name")
        coder.encode(self.info, forKey: "info")
        coder.encode(self.score, forKey: "score")
    }
}
```

```
class BadgeFactory {
    ...

    func addBadges(score: Float) -> [Badge] {
        ...
        let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self.userBadges)
        defaults.set(data, forKey: BadgeFactory.b)
        ...
    }

    func getBadges() -> [Badge] {
        guard let data = defaults.data(forKey: BadgeFactory.b) else { return [] }
        return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(ofClass: Badge, from: data) ?? [] 
    }
    
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the error likely comes from this line in your viewDidLoad:

```swift
bf.getBadges()
```

This will try to execute `self.defaults.array(forKey: BadgeFactory.b) as! [Badge]`

At this point UserDefaults are empty (because you do that before calling `.addBadges` or providing any other value for the key). So `self.defaults.array(forKey: BadgeFactory.b)` will evaluate to nil and the forced casting `as! [Badge]` will fail at runtime with a message like the one you provided.

To resolve I would adjust the function like this:

```swift
func getBadges() -> [Badge] {
    return (self.defaults.array(forKey: BadgeFactory.b) as? [Badge]) ?? []
}
```