# Editing an Array Saved to User Defaults SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6.4

I have been trying to read data from an Array that is saved to User Defaults but the object types cause conflicts.

```
if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("data")==nil{
        let arrya : Array = ["Apple", "Apricot", "Banana", "Blueberry", "Cantaloupe", "Cherry",
            "Clementine", "Coconut", "Cranberry", "Fig", "Grape", "Grapefruit",
            "Kiwi fruit", "Lemon", "Lime", "Lychee", "Mandarine", "Mango",
            "Melon", "Nectarine", "Olive", "Orange", "Papaya", "Peach",
            "Pear", "Pineapple", "Raspberry", "Strawberry"]
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(arrya, forKey: "data")
}

var data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("data")
```

I am using **objectForKey** not **valueForKey** because of the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179668/how-to-save-and-read-array-of-array-in-nsuserdefaults-in-swift) question.

This question would answer my question, however... well... it doesn't. I still have issues. For example:

Trying

```
data.count
```

returns an error:

```
Value of type 'AnyObject?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
```

Trying:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = data[0]
```

returns an error:

```
Could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts supplied arguments
```

Why are the types not compatible? I was hoping that what I retrieve from User Defaults is the same type as this:

```
["hola", "alo", "ya", "shalom", bounjour", 1, 3, "ai"]
```

Thanks very much for any response in advance. All are welcome and greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cast to array

```
var data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("data") as! Array<String>
```

better use if let to check if casting failed

Answer (score 0):

The value returned from `objectForKey(_:)` is `AnyObject?` (because `NSUserDefaults` can store any type of object), but you are trying to treat the return value like an `Array`. It may well be an array, but the compiler doesn't know that, so you need to tell it.

If you are *sure* that the returned value will be an array of strings, you can force case it when you initialise your `data` variable:

```
var data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("data") as! [String]
```

The compiler will now know that `data` is of type `[String]`, and use subscripting and properties like `count` on it.