# Swift store array with UserDefaults

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

So I'm trying to store some posts id's basically so I can know what the user has read so I can show a "seen" button.

```
var actual_data = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "seen_posts")
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(actual_data?.insert(321, at: 0), forKey: "seen_posts")
```

I have tried this, but it doesn't seem to work, `Ambiguous use of 'insert(_:at:)'`

Updated

```
var actual_data = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "seen_posts")
UserDefaults.standard.set(actual_data?.append(["miodrag"]), forKey: "seen_posts")
```

Comment: move `actual_data?.insert(321, at: 0)` to the line above it and set actual_data forKey

Comment: BTW naming an array actual_data is misleading

Comment: What will be a better name?

Comment: just omit data from it or add array which it is not needed as you can always check its type. BTW the conventions is camelCase (not underscore)

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179668/how-to-save-and-read-array-of-array-in-nsuserdefaults-in-swift

Comment: @LeoDabus doesn't work

Comment: ... and don't use `setValue:forKey` unless you can explain why KVC is explicitly needed.

Comment: @vadian can you post an example on how to set an array for UserDefaults, basically needs to contain an array with IDS

Comment: `UserDefaults.standard.set(actual_data, forKey: "seen_posts")`

Comment: Make sure you are not testing it using a playground (it doesn't work)

Comment: @LeoDabus I need to read the current data and  add a value to the array and save it

Comment: @LeoDabus check my updated posts, which doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of the error is that the compiler cannot infer the type of the array.

Spend an extra line to read, change and write the data, for example:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
var seenPosts : [Int]
if let actual = defaults.array(forKey: "seen_posts") as? [Int] {
     seenPosts = actual
} else {
     seenPosts = [Int]() 
}
seenPosts.insert(321, at: 0)
defaults.set(seenPosts, forKey: "seen_posts")
```

or if the default key `seen_posts` is registered – as recommended – simpler

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
var seenPosts = defaults.array(forKey: "seen_posts") as! [Int]
seenPosts.insert(321, at: 0)
defaults.set(seenPosts, forKey: "seen_posts")
```

Comment: let array = defaults.object(forKey:"seen_posts") as? [String] ?? [String]()
        debugPrint(array) So I have added this to test it, and I get an empty array

Comment: According to your (first) code the array is `[Int]`.