# Storing and reading UITextview's value from UserDefaults in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm storing the `UITextView.text` as array in `UserDefaults`.

```
let array = notesText.text
UserDefaults.standard.set(array, forKey: "notesKey")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

I'm reading the array as:

```
let notesArray = UserDefaults .standard .object ( forKey: "notesKey" )
print( "Data: \( notesArray )" )
```

I want to dispaly the array with `indexpath.row` in `UITableView`.

I have a UITableview and onclick of cell it dispalys detailview on the detailview I have a navigation button onclick of it it displays another view where i have the uitextview,on clcik of savebutton it should save the text in uitextview and when i come back to this view i need the uitextview to display what was saved.

Could you help me do that?

Comment: Have you looked for a way to do that yet? I just searched on google for the *exact* title of your question, and found numerous solutions...

Comment: I did search but didnt find solution

Comment: `notesText.text` is not an array, it's a string.

Comment: What's you actual question? What issue are you having?

Comment: i want to save the uitextview.text in nsuserdefault and get the value as nsarray

Comment: An array of what?  Words? Characters? Lines? You can't get the value of a text view's text as an array because it isn't an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to save and read array of array in NSUserdefaults in swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179668/how-to-save-and-read-array-of-array-in-nsuserdefaults-in-swift)

Comment: @dan please check the updated question

Comment: @rmaddy please check the updated question

Comment: It still doesn't make much sense, no offence. Just because you named a variable `array` doesn't make its type an `Array`. Are you triying to make a notes app - so you have a screen where you input text, you want to store all inputs in an array, and display them in rows on a table?

Comment: Yes a notes app