# Save and read arrays into UserDefaults swift

Tags: ios, arrays, iphone, swift, nsuserdefaults

I've always struggled with arrays; I´m trying to save some arrays into user defaults. my arrays are String, Double and UIImageView type. I declared them like:

```
var nameHospital = [String]()
var distanceBetweenLocations = [Double]()
var images = [UIImage]() // <-- Haven't tried with this yet
```

and I try to save them in UserDefaults like this...

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(nameHospital, forKey: "name")
```

And call theme like so

```
UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "name")
```

Then when I want to print them to see if it worked, it only prints one value (last value of the For Cycle) then I set my print inside the for and as I was expecting, it printed the value and then replaced it for the next value and so on.

What am I doing wrong? How can I call each value separately  for further functions? And How can I do this but with my UIImage array? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: [Edit] your question with actual code that is causing you issues.

Comment: And please read the documentation for `UserDefaults`. It tells you what you can store.

Answer (score 1):

You are see this one : [**NSUserDefault**](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/05/save-data-using-nsuserdefaults-in-swift.html)

**SAVE :**

```
 let kUserDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
 kUserDefault.setObject(["KIRIT" , "MODI" , "FIRST" , "LAST"], forKey: "nameArray")
 kUserDefault.synchronize()
```

**READ :**

```
kUserDefault.arrayForKey("nameArray")!
kUserDefault.objectForKey("nameArray")!
kUserDefault.valueForKey("nameArray")
```

**For Swift 3**

```
let kUserDefault = UserDefaults.standard
kUserDefault.set(["KIRIT" , "MODI" , "FIRST" , "LAST"], forKey: "nameArray")
kUserDefault.synchronize()

let data = kUserDefault.array(forKey: "nameArray")! as? [String] ?? [String]()
print(data)
```

for more info visit [store value in userDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179668/how-to-save-and-read-array-of-array-in-nsuserdefaults-in-swift)

Comment: @Foolish, thanks to improved the answer.