# How to store array of values in NSUserDefaults in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have an array of values `var studentIDs: [Int] = []`.I want to store all the values in the array on userDefaults.Please Help.

Comment: And the problem is ...?

Comment: Here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179668/how-to-save-and-read-array-of-array-in-nsuserdefaults-in-swift?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let array = [1, 2, 9, 3, 22]

UserDefaults.standard.set(array, forKey: "studentIDs")

//get id's array from user defaults
let studentIdsArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "studentIDs")
```

There are plenty of questions/solutions, here is one:
[how to save and read array of array in NSUserdefaults in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179668/how-to-save-and-read-array-of-array-in-nsuserdefaults-in-swift)

But as another user said, please take a look at the official documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults

Comment: Instead of posting an answer with links to duplicates, simply close the question as a duplicate.