# App Delegate weird error when trying to add element to NSUserDefaults

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, swift2, sigabrt

I've got a really weird error while running my app on Xcode 7 (Swift 2) that shows a "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" running error message in the App Delegate class of my app. However I've actually already got this "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" running error message in the App Delegate class lots of times, mainly when deleting an outlet reference in my code and forgetting to also delete it from storyboard. But that's certainly the first time I've got this same error when trying to make the command:

```
let wasteGain = WastesGainsClass(value: enteredMoney, originOrCat: segControlArray[segControl.selectedSegmentIndex], specification: plusEspecTField.text!, date: dateArray, mode: "gain")

gains.append(wasteGain)

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(gains, forKey: "gains")
```

What happens is that if I just comment the line `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(gains, forKey: "gains")` the app doesn't crash! So the error might just be in that line.

If anyone could help me, I`d thank you so much.

PS: WastesGainsClass format is like this:

```
class WastesGainsClass {

    var value:Int = 0
    var origin:String
    var specification:String
    var date:[String]
    var mode:String
    var rowMode:Int = 0

    init(value:Int, originOrCat:String, specification:String, date:[String], mode:String) {

        self.value = value
        self.origin = originOrCat
        self.specification = specification
        self.date = date
        self.mode = mode

    }

}
```

Comment: Only property list compliant types (`NSNumber`, `NSString`, `NSDate`, `NSData`) and the collection types `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` can be saved with `NSUserDefaults`. The collection types must contain also property list compliant types. For custom classes your class must conform to `NSCoding` to be archived with `NSKeyedArchiver/Unarchiver`

Comment: @vadian You should add that as an answer; that's exactly what the problem/solution is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Attempt to set a non-property-list object as an NSUserDefaults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720611/attempt-to-set-a-non-property-list-object-as-an-nsuserdefaults)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/):

> The NSUserDefaults class provides convenience methods for accessing
>   common types such as floats, doubles, integers, Booleans, and URLs. A
>   default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or
>   for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString,
>   NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any
>   other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an
>   instance of NSData.

In Swift you can also use:

- `Int`, `UInt`, `Double`, `Float` and `Bool` types because they are automatically bridged to `NSNumber`;
- `String` bridged to `NSString`
- `[AnyObject]` because it is bridged to `NSArray`;
- `[NSObject: AnyObject]` because it is bridged to `NSDictionary`.

Of course type of array elements and dictionary values must be one of above types. Dictionary key type must be `NSString` (or bridged `String`).

To store instances of any other class you have two options:

1. Your custom class must be subclass of `NSObject` and conform to
   `NSCoding` protocol and then you can archive object of this class to `NSData` with `NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject()` and save it to `NSUserDefaults` and later retrieve it from `NSUserDefaults` and unarchive with `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData()`:

   ```
   import Foundation

   class WastesGainsClass: NSObject, NSCoding {
       var value: Int

       init(value: Int) {
           self.value = value
       }

       required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
           value = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("value") as! Int
       }

       func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
           aCoder.encodeObject(value, forKey: "value")
       }
   }

   var gains = [WastesGainsClass(value: 1), WastesGainsClass(value: 2)]
   NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(gains.map {  NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject($0) }, forKey: "gains")

   if let gainsData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("gains") as? [NSData] {
       gains = gainsData.map { NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData($0) as! WastesGainsClass }
   }
   ```
2. You can save your custom object properties to dictionary and store that
   dictionary in `NSUserDefaults`:

   ```
   import Foundation

   class WastesGainsClass {
       var value: Int

       init(value: Int) {
           self.value = value
       }
   }

   extension WastesGainsClass {
       convenience init(dict: [NSObject: AnyObject]) {
           self.init(value: dict["value"] as? Int ?? 0)
       }

       func toDict() -> [NSObject: AnyObject] {
           var d = [NSObject: AnyObject]()
           d["value"] = value
           return d
       }
   }

   var gains = [WastesGainsClass(value: 1), WastesGainsClass(value: 2)]

   NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(gains.map { $0.toDict() }, forKey: "gains")

   if let dicts = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("gains") as? [[NSObject: AnyObject]] {
       gains = dicts.map { WastesGainsClass(dict: $0) }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

`NSUserDefaults` unfortunately can't accept arbitrary objects, only objects that can be encoded in a Property List. See [Apple's reference guide for Property Lists](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i) to learn which objects can be stored.

If you need to save several `WastesGainsClass` objects, you may wish to write a method that returns a `Dictionary` encoding their Property List-representable properties, and an initializer that accepts such a `Dictionary` to restore the object.

However, if you truly need to save multiple custom objects like this, you probably don't want to use `NSUserDefaults` at all. Consider a document-based app, and look into `NSCoding`.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted tries to save an array of custom objects to NSUserDefaults. You can't do that. Implementing the NSCoding methods doesn't help. You can only store things like NSArray, NSDictionary, NSString, NSData, NSNumber, and NSDate in NSUserDefaults.

You need to convert the object to NSData (like you have in some of the code) and store that NSData in NSUserDefaults. You can even store an NSArray of NSData if you need to.

see this post : [Attempt to set a non-property-list object as an NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720611/attempt-to-set-a-non-property-list-object-as-an-nsuserdefaults)

Comment: `NSCoding` protocol is used when you archive instance of custom class to `NSData` with `NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject()` and later retrieve it with `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData`.

Comment: @mixel: Please reread again (and remove your down vote): the answer is relevant and the post is actually a duplicate from the referred post. Ok I mentioned NSCodings as well because it was mentioned in the other answer (and not here). But Nicolas is having EXACTLY the same problem and error