# Error with NSUserDefaults , while setting NSMutable array as object in iOS, objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I tried to set `NSMutableArray` as object in `NSUserDefault`.but it gives following error.

> **Attempt to set a non-property-list**

this is how I tried it.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:OutboundArray forKey:@"outbound"];
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

**NOTE :** `OutboundArray` type is NSMutableArray. What is the wrong with this.I do this inside a method.hope your help.

this is how I assign value to OutboundArray

```
- (void)assignvaluedForarrays
{
    OutboundArray = nil;
    InboundArray = nil;

    FlightSearchSelected *flightSearch = [FlightSearchSelected new];
    JourneyTy = flightSearch.returnJType;
    DirectRNot = flightSearch.returnNonStoporNot;
    fromAcode = flightSearch.returnFromPort;
    toAcode = flightSearch.returnToPort;

    FlightCnt = FinalDetails.FlightCount;


    OutboundArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    InboundArray = [NSMutableArray array];


    //all round trips
    if ([JourneyTy isEqualToString:@"true"])
    {

            for (int i=0;i<FlightCnt;i++)
            {
                FinalValues *finalValue = testingArray[i];
                NSString *legNumber = finalValue.legnumber;

                if ([legNumber isEqualToString:@"1"])
                {
                    [OutboundArray addObject:testingArray[i]];

                }
                else
                {
                    [InboundArray addObject:testingArray[i]];
                }
            }


    }
    //only one ways trips
    else
    {
        self.finaltableViewbottomLayout.constant = 180;
        for (int i = 0;i<FlightCnt;i++)
        {
            [OutboundArray addObject:testingArray[i]];

        }

    }
}
```

*testingArray data comes from the previous view controller according to indexpath of the table view.

Comment: Are you sure, OutboundArray is actually an instance of NSMutableArray ? As the error suggests, you're attempting to store an object that is not part of the p-list in NSUserDefaults.

A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an instance of NSData.

Comment: for OutboundArray I added objects(NSString).yep I tried with NSData also like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720611/attempt-to-set-a-non-property-list-object-as-an-nsuserdefaults.but nothing happened

Comment: Show us the full code rather than just snippets. Your current code sample works just fine in my test environment.

Comment: @Tander updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Okay, having a look at your code - the issue is here:

```
[OutboundArray addObject:testingArray[i]];
```

My bet is that `testingArray` contains non-property-list item. So not any of the following instances:

> NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary.

If your `testingArray` has a custom `NSObject` inside it, this is where your problem is. If that is the case, then you need to archive the array into `NSData` first, before you store it in `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: yes testingArray has a custom `NSObject` I will do it thanx for the help

Comment: No problem. If it solves your issue, remember to mark the answer as correct to help others who may face the same issue.

Comment: definitely , I upvoted, if it works I will mark as correct.thanx