# Save custom object to NSUserDefaults in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, swift2

I have a class say,

```
class GroupClass{
    var groupId: String = ""
    var groupName: String = ""
}
```

I want to be able to store its object in `NSUserDefaults`. I tried this way,

```
let group = GroupClass()
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject(group, forKey: "group")
defaults.synchronize()
```

and retrieved it following way,

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()        
var group = defaults.objectForKey("group") as! GroupClass
```

It threw exception `Using non-property obect` and crashed. What is the right way to do it in Swift?

Also tried the following way,

```
class GroupClass{
    var groupId: String = ""
    var groupName: String = ""

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.groupId = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("groupId") as! String
        self.groupName = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("groupName") as! String

    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.groupId, forKey: "groupId")
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.groupName, forKey: "groupName")

    } 
}
```

But, `let group = GroupClass(coder:NSCoder())` gives problem.

Comment: use NSKeyedArchiver for this

Comment: @EICaptain Can you please provide a demo code, I am new to Swift.

Comment: 2nd answer is in swift http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720611/attempt-to-set-a-non-property-list-object-as-an-nsuserdefaults

Comment: @EICaptain I tried that way `let group = GroupClass(coder:NSCoder())` this gives problem

Comment: full solution is in that answer ... check carefully .. there may be some mistake

Comment: @EICaptain is this correct way to create object? `let group = GroupClass(coder:NSCoder())` as it says `cannot be sent to an abstract object of class NSCoder: Create a concrete instance!'`

Comment: @DarkDrake are you able to solve this question? Can you please upload the solution if you solve this.

Answer (score 2):

You can't save class reference to `userdefault`. group is your reference of your class. why you are saving it. it just points your class in memory. it will be destroy after completing it's task. userdefaults are for storing data like strings, arrays, dictionary etc. you should not need to store reference in database. i don't think so.

you can set group.groupId or group.groupName in userdefaults. then also if you want to store that then you can convert it in `nsdata` by `NSKeyedArchiver` and save that data to `nsuserdefault` and `unarchive` it when it needed by `NSKeyedUnArchiver`.

Hope this will help :)