# Swift how may I save contacts in defaults

Tags: swift, contacts

Good morning all, I followed this tutorial 
I am able to add a new contact and retrieve existing contacts , but what I am trying to accomplish is save the list that I add in a mutableArray and use that array to populate my TableView. I am getting this error

Contacts Introduction[5166:4971615] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property list object (
    "!$_, value=>\"\n), emailAddresses=(\n    \"!$_, value=>\"\n), postalAddresses=(\n)>"
) for key contactsKey'

Here

```
 func insertNewObject(sender: NSNotification) {

        print("How Many Times am I getting here ??")

        if let contact = sender.userInfo?["contactToAdd"] as? CNContact {
            objects.insert(contact, atIndex: 0)
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
            self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        }

        print("How Many Objects ",objects.count)

        let contactArray = objects as [CNContact]
        let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        prefs.setValue(contactArray, forKey: "contactsKey")

    }
```

Any Help is appreciated.

Regards
JZ

Comment: To save an array of objects in user defaults, the objects have to be types that are valid for a property list.  (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html)  Can you use the contact's `identifier` string instead (and look up the contact when you need it)?

Answer (score 1):

`NSUserDefaults` is backed by a [property list](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i), so you can only add objects to it that are property list objects ([see list of compatible objects here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH3-54303)).

`CNContact` is not on that list, so you can't add it to `NSUserDefaults` directly.

One way around this is to serialize/deserialize the `CNContact` object manually into something compatible like an `NSDictionary` or `NSData` ([like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19720674/316891)) which you can then save to `NSUserDefaults`.