# How to store an array in NSUserDefaults? swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to store an array in userDefaults but i am getting this error when i run my app:

'Attempt to insert non-property list object (
    "Morning_Star_2.Event(title: Optional(\"test title\"), location: Optional(\"Test Location\"))"
) for key test'

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var txtTitle: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var txtLocation: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var txtDate: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var txtTime: UITextField!

    var eventsArray = [Event]()


       @IBAction func btnSave() {

        let savedEvents = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "test")

        let event = Event(eventTitle: txtTitle.text!, eventLocation: txtLocation.text!)

        if let tempEvents = savedEvents {
            eventsArray = tempEvents as! [Event]
            eventsArray.append(event)

        }
        else {
            let event = Event(eventTitle: txtTitle.text!, eventLocation: txtLocation.text!)
            eventsArray.append(event)
        }

        UserDefaults.standard.set(eventsArray, forKey: "test")


        //print(eventsArray)

        }

}
```

Comment: Your array has custom objects which can not be stored automatically in user defaults. Take a look here how to properly do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315948/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-nsuserdefaults

Comment: Please [search on the error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+Attempt+to+insert+non-property+list+object) before posting.

Comment: you can not store object directly to UserDefaults so, it give this type of error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attempt to set a non-property-list object as an NSUserDefaults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720611/attempt-to-set-a-non-property-list-object-as-an-nsuserdefaults)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store custom objects in UserDefaults, your objects must

1. Inherit from NSObject
2. Conform to the NSCoding protocol

An example of the class implementation could look like this:

```
class Event: NSObject, NSCoding {

    private var eventTitle: String!
    private var eventLocation: String!

    init(eventTitle: String, eventLocation: String) {
        self.eventTitle = eventTitle
        self.eventLocation = eventLocation
    }

    override init() {

    }

    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.init()
        eventTitle = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "eventTitle") as? String
        eventLocation = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "eventLocation") as? String
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(eventTitle, forKey: "eventTitle")
        aCoder.encode(eventLocation, forKey: "eventLocation")
    }

}
```

Now, you can only store certain objects in UserDefaults. Luckily the type Data can be stored in UserDefaults. You then need to convert your array to Data, and then store it.

```
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: eventsArray) 
// This calls the encode function of your Event class

UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "test")
/* This saves the object to a buffer, but you will need to call synchronize, 
before it is actually saved to UserDefaults */

UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

When you retrieve the data it comes back as Any?, which will have to be casted to your object:

```
if let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "test") as? Data {
    if let storedData = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? [Event] {
            // In here you can access your array
    }
}
```