# store NSMutableArray into NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to store `NSMutableArray` into `NSUserDefaults` as follows, but getting the following error.

```
(lldb) po pOrderElements
<__NSArrayM 0x174256b90>(
{
    category = 1;
    imagePath = "products/chicken-kabob.png";
    name = "Baked Chicken";
    price = "5.49";
}
)

NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:pOrderElements forKey:@"tableViewData"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property
>   list object (
>           {
>           category = 1;
>           id = "";
>           imagePath = "products/chicken-kabob.png";
>           name = "Baked Chicken";
>           price = "5.49";
>       } ) for key tableViewData'

Comment: see this for your error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720611/attempt-to-set-a-non-property-list-object-as-an-nsuserdefaults

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, any idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43222681/store-custom-objects-in-nsuserdefaults

Comment: Convert NSArray to NSData