# Store Custom Objects in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

I am trying to store a custom objects as follows, but I am getting an error.

```
// store data
NSMutableArray *archiveArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:pOrderElements.count];
for (id orderObject in pOrderElements) {
    NSData *personEncodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:orderObject];
    [archiveArray addObject:personEncodedObject];
}

NSUserDefaults *userData = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userData setObject:archiveArray forKey:@"personDataArray"];


// retrive data
NSData *data = [userData objectForKey:@"personDataArray"];
// the following line throws an error
id retrieveData = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

here is my pOrderElements

```
(lldb) po pOrderElements
<__NSArrayM 0x174256b90>(
{
    category = 1;
    imagePath = "products/chicken-kabob.png";
    name = "Baked Chicken";
    price = "5.49";
}
)
```

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray bytes]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x174264f40'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store custom objects in NSUserDefaults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315948/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-nsuserdefaults)

Comment: I referred to following answer, but I got the error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720611/attempt-to-set-a-non-property-list-object-as-an-nsuserdefaults

Comment: Have you implemented encoder decoder?

Comment: [don't post same questions again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43222415/store-nsmutablearray-into-nsuserdefaults)

Comment: It is duplicate question but I have posted complete answer according to your need.Please check it and let me know @hotspring

Comment: retrieve = NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *arrayOfImages = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"personDataArray"];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You unarchive incorrect object. You store NSArray to NSUserDefaults

```
NSArray * archiveArray = [userData objectForKey:@"personDataArray"];
for (NSData *personEncodedObject in archiveArray) {
    id personObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:personEncodedObject];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First you create custom class Like below.

CustomObject.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CustomObject : NSObject

@property(strong,nonatomic)NSString *name;

@end
```

CustomObject.m

```
#import "CustomObject.h"

@implementation CustomObject



- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    //Encode properties, other class variables, etc
    [encoder encodeObject:self.name forKey:@"name"];

}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if((self = [super init])) {
        //decode properties, other class vars
        self.name = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Then create `CustomObject` class object and store in `NSUserDefaults`

Stored your object like this

```
CustomObject *object =[CustomObject new];
object.name = @"test";

NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[arr  addObject:object];

NSData *encodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:arr];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:encodedObject forKey:@"storeObject"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

get custom object from `NSUserDefaults` like this

```
NSData *storedEncodedObject = [defaults objectForKey:@"storeObject"];
    NSArray *arrStoreObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:storedEncodedObject];
    for (int i=0; i<arrStoreObject.count; i++)
    {
        CustomObject *storedObject = [arrStoreObject objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"%@",storedObject.name);

    }
```