# How to save a Array with (Multiple Types) in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

This is pretty simple but can't seem to find the correct information to solve saving an array like this in User Defaults.

It says it's not a property that NSUser Defaults Excepts.

Code:

```
    var notificationList: [(type: String,imageName: String, text: String, date: String, seen: Bool)] = [(type: "Default",imageName: "ClearPartioned", text: "", date: "", seen: true)]


    if (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "notificationList")) == nil { // first time launching

        print("making notification list")

        UserDefaults.standard.set(notificationList, forKey: "notificationList")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

        print("\(notificationList)")

    } else {

        print("getting saved array")

        notificationList = (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "notificationList") as! [(type: String, imageName: String, text: String, date: String, seen: Bool)])

        print("\(notificationList)")
    }
```

[image]

**Update:**

This is closer but gives error found in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26469457/saving-custom-swift-class-with-nscoding-to-userdefaults). These are the closet answers I have been able to find and there either out dated or crash the system.

Code:

```
    if (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "notificationList")) == nil { // first time launching

        print("making notification list")

        let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: notificationList)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: "notificationList")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    } else {

        print("getting saved array")

        notificationList = (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "notificationList") as! [(type: String, imageName: String, text: String, date: String, seen: Bool)])

        print("\(notificationList)")
    }
```

**Update 2:** This is best answer implementation From Dhiru

Code:

```
  if (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "notificationList")) == nil { // first time launching
        print("making notification list")

        let notificationData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: notificationList)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(notificationData, forKey: "notificationList")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    } else {

        print("getting saved array")

        let decodedData  = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "notificationList") as! Data
        let notificationList = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decodedData) as AnyObject

        print("\(notificationList)")
    }
```

Its giving me an error that crashes system

```
   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c011f380'
   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Im sure this code would fix it but this is horribly implemented with multiple errors below because I have no clue how to use this code.

Code:

```
   func (coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        if let notificationList = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("notificationList") {
            self.notificationList = notificationList
        }
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        if let notificationList = notificationList {
            aCoder.encodeObject(notificationList, forKey: "notificationList")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure about tuples, but custom object have to confront the `NSCoding` protocol to encode the params into data, then only can be saved in `UserDefault`

Comment: Try [searching on the error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+attempt+to+insert+non-property+list+object). This has been covered many times before.

Comment: Save it as Data using `NSKeyedArchiver`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I actually save a Custom Object created in the app in **Swift 4**.

First, we create 3 protocols for our purpose of saving the custom object in `UserDefaults`. The logic behind is to convert the `Custom Object` into a normalized `Dictionary/Array` form.

> This can be applied to any kind of Object which you have created.

The 3 protocols are:

1. `Decoder` (Used to decode the dictionary into custom object)
2. `Encoder` (Used to encode the custom object into dictionary)
3. `UserDefaultsProtocol` (Used to save, delete, update & retrieve the custom object from `UserDefault`)

**Decoder Protocol**

```
protocol Decoder {
    associatedtype T
    static func decode(dictionary: [String: Any]) -> T
}
```

**Encoder Protocol**

```
protocol Encoder {
    func encode() -> [String: Any]
}
```

**UserDefaultsProtocol**

```
protocol UserDefaultsDelegate: class {
    associatedtype T
    func saveToUserDefaults()
    static func removeFromUserDefaults()
    static func retrieveFromUserDefaults() -> T?
}
```

As per your question, **NotificationList** Object would look like this

```
class NotificationList {
    var type: String = ""
    var imageName: String = ""
    var text: String = ""
    var date: String = ""
    var seen: Bool = false
}
```

Now, you need to confirm all the 3 mentioned protocols to `NotificationList`. (Swift Best Practice: Use of Extensions & Protocols)

```
class NotificationList {
    private struct Constants {
        static let RootKey = "notification_list"
        static let TypeKey = "type"
        static let ImageNameKey = "image_name"
        static let TextKey = "text"
        static let DateKey = "date"
        static let SeenKey = "seen"
    }

    var type: String = ""
    var imageName: String = ""
    var text: String = ""
    var date: String = ""
    var seen: Bool = false

    typealias T = NotificationList
}

extension NotificationList: Encoder {
    func encode() -> [String : Any] {
        return [
            Constants.TypeKey: type,
            Constants.ImageNameKey: imageName,
            Constants.TextKey: text,
            Constants.DateKey: date,
            Constants.SeenKey: seen
        ]
    }
}

extension NotificationList: Decoder {
    static func decode(dictionary: [String: Any]) -> NotificationList {
        let type = dictionary[Constants.TypeKey] as! String
        let imageName = dictionary[Constants.ImageNameKey] as! String
        let text = dictionary[Constants.TextKey] as! String
        let date = dictionary[Constants.DateKey] as! String
        let seen = dictionary[Constants.SeenKey] as! Bool

        let notificationList = NotificationList()
        notificationList.type = type
        notificationList.imageName = imageName
        notificationList.text = text
        notificationList.date = date
        notificationList.seen = seen
        return notificationList
    }
}

extension NotificationList: UserDefaultsDelegate {

    func saveToUserDefaults() {
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(encode(), forKey: Constants.RootKey)
    }

    static func retrieveFromUserDefaults() -> NotificationList? {
        guard let encodedNotificationList = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: Constants.RootKey) else {
            return nil
        }
        return NotificationList.decode(dictionary: encodedNotificationList)
    }

    static func removeFromUserDefaults() {
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: Constants.RootKey)
    }
}
```

**How to save NotificationList to UserDefaults?**

```
var notificationList = NotificationList()
notificationList.type = "Default"
notificationList.imageName = "ClearPartioned"
notificationList.text = ""
notificationList.date = ""
notificationList.seen = true
```

**Save to UserDefaults**

```
notificationList.saveToUserDefaults()
```

**Retrieve from UserDefaults**

```
if let notificationList = NotificationList.retrieveFromUserDefaults() {
      // You will get the instance of notification list saved in UserDefaults
}
```

**HOW TO SAVE ARRAY OF NOTIFICATION LIST?**

Say `notificationLists` contains the array of notificationList objects.

```
var notificationListsArray = [[String: Any]]()

notificationLists.forEach {
     notificationListsArray.append($0.encode())
}
```

**Save that array of dictionary to UserDefaults**

```
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(notificationListsArray, forValue: "notificationLists")
```

Comment: Wow quite a set up! It's the best and really only answer so far so I'll mark it.

Comment: I hope it helped to solve your problem. As It requires some setup upfront. But after that, you can use it in anywhere in your application, which is the real power of Swift.

Comment: Yep Thank You this is a incredibly well written answer

Answer (score 3):

You have to store your Object  in form of `Data`
Convert into data using
`NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject:)`

Convert back to Object using
 `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with:)`

**Saving Data for UserDefaults**

```
let notificationData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: notificationList)
UserDefaults.standard.set(notificationData, forKey: "notificationList")
```

**Retrive Data from User UserDefaults**

```
let decodedData  = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "notificationList") as! Data
let notificationList = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decodedData) as! AnyObject
```

Comment: its giving me "unrecognized selector sent to instance" I think its half way there

Comment: It doesn't give specific line (its one of those kind of errors) I updated question

Comment: @Dhiru `notificationList` is not confirming to NSCoding protocol. So you can not do `Archive` & `UnArchive` the value