# How to for loop in userDefaults swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I am saving data into userDeafults using 2 textfield as String, String but I want to know how to retrieve all the data to display either using loop or function

```
    let save = UserDefaults.standard

    let heading = headingText.text
    let description = desxriptionTexr.text
    save.set(description, forKey: heading!)
```

Comment: I think is not a correct way to do. You can read my answer just below

Comment: a possible answer to your question: [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44940571/4447772)

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To get all keys and corresponding values in **UserDefaults**, you can use:

```
for (key, value) in UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation() {
            print("\(key) = \(value) \n")
}
```

In **swift 3**, you can store and retrieve using:

```
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(token, forKey: "user_auth_token")
print("\(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "user_auth_token")!)")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think is not a correct way to do.

I suggest you to put your values into a dictionary and set the dictionary into the UserDefaults.

```
let DictKey = "MyKeyForDictionary"
var userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

// create your dictionary
let dict: [String : Any] = [
    "value1": "Test",
    "value2": 2
]

// set the dictionary
userDefaults.set(dict, forKey: DictKey)

// get the dictionary
let dictionary = userDefaults.object(forKey: DictKey) as? [String: Any]

// get value from
let value = dictionary?["value2"]


// iterate on all keys
guard let dictionary = dictionary else {
    return
}
for (key, val) in dictionary.enumerated() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are setting the key as heading and the value as description.
You can retrieve the value from userDefaults using `UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey:)`,  `UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: )`,`UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: )` etc functions.

So its better to save heading and description for 2 different keys may be like

```
let save = UserDefaults.standard
let heading = headingText.text
let description = desxriptionTexr.text
save.set(description, forKey: "description")
save.set(heading, forKey: "heading")
```

And you could retrieve like

```
 let description = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:"description")
 let heading = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:"heading")
```

Comment: There is even `string(forKey:`

Comment: I just gave it as general. I have updated the answer. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple Strings, simply save value as array

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(YourStringArray, forKey: "stringArr")

let arr = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "stringArr")

for s in arr! {
    //do stuff
}
```