# saving swifty json array to user defaults

Tags: swift, alamofire, swifty-json

i have a json `data` which gives the following information:

```
let data = [
  {
    "QuestionTitle" : "Entomology is the science that studies",
    "Id" : 205,
    "Options" : [
      { "Option" : "Insects", "Id" : 810 },
      { "Option" : "The origin and history of technical and scientific terms", "Id" : 811 },
      { "Option" : "The formation of rocks", "Id" : 812 },
      { "Option" : "Behavior of human beings", "Id" : 809 }
    ]
  },
  {
    "QuestionTitle" : "A train running at the speed of 60 km\/hr crosses a pole in 9 seconds. What is the length of the train?",
    "Id" : 199,
    "Options" : [
      { "Option" : "120 metres", "Id" : 785 },
      { "Option" : "324 metres", "Id" : 787 },
      { "Option" : "180 metres", "Id" : 786 },
      { "Option" : "150 metres", "Id" : 788 }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am using swiftyjson. I want to save the entire array using nsuserdefaults.

```
GlobalVar.defaults.set(json, forKey: "questionArray")
GlobalVar.defaults.synchronize()
```

However, I get an error

> "[User Defaults] Attempt to set a non-property-list object".

Please assist i am new to swift. I have also checked other similar questions but seems to not work.

Comment: try setObject(json.object, forKey: "questionArray")

Comment: You can only save objects to `UserDefaults` that are `property list` types. In order to save a custom class/object, you need to convert it to `NSData` by archiving it. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315948/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-nsuserdefaults)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot save SwiftyJSON's custom type `JSON` to `UserDefaults` but you can save the *raw* array because a deserialized JSON collection type is property list compliant.

Just call `arrayObject` on the `JSON` object:

```
GlobalVar.defaults.set(json.arrayObject, forKey: "questionArray")
```

Comment: thank you for that. but i tried with json.arrayObject. And it worked.

Comment: i tried with json.arrayValue and it was giving me the above error.

Comment: You are right, my bad, I mixed up the types and edited the answer.

Comment: its okay :) after adding the json object to nsuserdefault i tried to retrieve it using: 
let questionObject  = GlobalVar.defaults.array(forKey: "questionArray")
I got back my original json array. Then, I did:
for questionDict in questionObject! {
            lblQuestion.text = questionDict["QuestionTitle"]
}

However, this gives me an error stating: "Type 'Any' has no subscript members"

Comment: You have to downcast the types `GlobalVar.defaults.array(forKey: "questionArray") as! [[String:Any]]` and `lblQuestion.text = questionDict["QuestionTitle"] as! String`. And be aware that the app will crash if you retrieve the array before saving it once.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3.0**

You can save SwiftyJSON custom type data as like below.

```
guard let rawData = try? json.rawData() else { return }
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(rawData, forKey: "Your_key")
```

And, To retrieve JSON data from UserDefaults, you can do like this way.

```
guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "Your_key") as? Data else { return }

let json = JSON(data)
```

Comment: Why do you use KVC to set and get the value? Is there a particular reason?

Answer (score 1):

**You can't save the array of dictionary directly to the** `NSUserDefault`, **You need to convert the object of array into** `NSData`

**See more for help:**

[Attempt to set a non-property-list object as an NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720611/attempt-to-set-a-non-property-list-object-as-an-nsuserdefaults)

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.0 | Xcode 9.1 | SwiftyJSON**

We can save array of dictionary directly, no problem.
Only, the problem is, how to retrieve it?

It barely downcast to array of dictionary (say [[String : Any]]). for this, we required SwiftyJSON pods `import SwiftyJSON // Don't forget this`

```
let arrayOfDictionary = [
                         { 
                           "VersionNumber" : "1.0.0.0", 
                                  "FormID" : "18"
                          },
                         {
                           "VersionNumber" : "1.0.0.3",
                                  "FormID" : "19"
                          }
                         ]
```

Saving it directly to UserDefaults like :

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(saveFormDetails, forKey: "FormDetails")
```

Retrieving from UserDefaults :

```
let savedFormDetailsData = JSON.init(rawValue:UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "FormDetails"))
```

Now, savedFormDetailsData is the array of dictionary back [*PropertyList Type*], for further we do :

```
for form in 0..<arrayOfDictionary.count {
    print("FormID :", savedFormDetailsData?[form]["FormID"]) 
    print("VersionNumber :", savedFormDetailsData?[form]["VersionNumber"])
}
```