# Not able to save a custom object array save to UserDefault in Swift 4

Tags: cncontact, userdefaults, swift4.2

I have searched for around 2 days on `Google` and also on `StackOverflow` but no luck.

My custom object is almost a replica of the `CNContact` object.

```
struct Contact: Codable {

let fullName, phones, emails: String
let imageDataAvailable, expanded: Bool
let thumbnailImageData, imageData: Data
let contactType: Int
let identifier: String
let namePrifix, givenName, middleName, familyName, previousFamilyName, nameSuffix, nickName, organizationName, departmentName, jobTitle, phoneticGivenName, phoneticMiddleName, phoneticFamilyName, phoneticOrganizationName, note: String
let birthday, nonGregorianBirthday: DateComponents
let dates: [ContactDate]
let postalAddresses: [PostalAddress]
let urlAddresses: [UrlAddress]
let contactRelations: [ContactRelation]
let socialProfiles: [SocialProfile]
let instantMessageAddresses: [InstantMessageAddress]
let phoneNumbers: [PhoneNumber]
let emailAddresses: [Email]
}

struct PostalAddress: Codable {
    let label, street, subLocality, city, subAdministativeArea, state, postalCode, country, isoCountryCode: String
}

struct UrlAddress: Codable {
    let label, value: String
}

struct ContactRelation: Codable {
    let label, name: String
}

struct SocialProfile: Codable {
    let label, urlString, userName, userIdentifier, service: String
}

struct PhoneNumber: Codable {
    let label, stringValue: String
}

struct Email: Codable {
    let label, value: String
}

struct InstantMessageAddress: Codable {
    let label, userName, service: String
}

struct ContactDate: Codable {
    let label: String
    let value: DateComponents
}
```

I try to save an array of the `Contact` object to `UserDefault` but all time it just gives me the same error.

Please help me with solving this issue.

**Edit 1**

I tried to convert the array to data using the below code but no luck I got another error

**Code**

```
do {
        let contactJson = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: arrContact, options: .prettyPrinted)
        CommonFunctions.setUserDefaultValue(key: WSKey.contacts.rawValue, value: contactJson)
    } catch let parsingError {
        print("Error", parsingError)
    }
```

**ERROR**

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (_SwiftValue)'

My array with `debugDescription` command in log is as follow

> "[Storedge.Contact(fullName: \"Kate  Bell\", phones: \"(555) 564-8583\n(415) 555-3695\", emails: \"kate-bell@mac.com\", imageDataAvailable: false, expanded: false, thumbnailImageData: 0 bytes, imageData: 0 bytes, contactType: 0, identifier: \"177C371E-701D-42F8-A03B-C61CA31627F6\", namePrifix: \"\", givenName: \"Kate\", middleName: \"\", familyName: \"Bell\", previousFamilyName: \"\", nameSuffix: \"\", nickName: \"\", organizationName: \"Creative Consulting\", departmentName: \"\", jobTitle: \"Producer\", phoneticGivenName: \"\", phoneticMiddleName: \"\", phoneticFamilyName: \"\", phoneticOrganizationName: \"\", note: \"\", birthday: calendar: gregorian (fixed) year: 1978 month: 1 day: 20 isLeapMonth: false , nonGregorianBirthday: isLeapMonth: false , dates: [], postalAddresses: [Storedge.PostalAddress(label: \"*$!!$*\", street: \"165 Davis Street\", subLocality: \"\", city: \"Hillsborough\", subAdministativeArea: \"\", state: \"CA\", postalCode: \"94010\", country: \"\", isoCountryCode: \"us\")], urlAddresses: [Storedge.UrlAddress(label: \"*$!!$*\", value: \"www.icloud.com\")], contactRelations: [], socialProfiles: [], instantMessageAddresses: [], phoneNumbers: [Storedge.PhoneNumber(label: \"*$!!$*\", stringValue: \"(555) 564-8583\"), Storedge.PhoneNumber(label: \"*$!!$*\", stringValue: \"(415) 555-3695\")], emailAddresses: [Storedge.Email(label: \"*$!!$*\", value: \"kate-bell@mac.com\")]), Storedge.Contact(fullName: \"Daniel  Higgins\", phones: \"555-478-7672\n(408) 555-5270\n(408) 555-3514\", emails: \"d-higgins@mac.com\", imageDataAvailable: false, expanded: false, thumbnailImageData: 0 bytes, imageData: 0 bytes, contactType: 0, identifier: \"AB211C5F-9EC9-429F-9466-B9382FF61035\", namePrifix: \"\", givenName: \"Daniel\", middleName: \"\", familyName: \"Higgins\", previousFamilyName: \"\", nameSuffix: \"Jr.\", nickName: \"\", organizationName: \"\", departmentName: \"\", jobTitle: \"\", phoneticGivenName: \"\", phoneticMiddleName: \"\", phoneticFamilyName: \"\", phoneticOrganizationName: \"\", note: \"Sister: Emily\", birthday: isLeapMonth: false , nonGregorianBirthday: isLeapMonth: false , dates: [], postalAddresses: [Storedge.PostalAddress(label: \"*$!!$*\", street: \"332 Laguna Street\", subLocality: \"\", city: \"Corte Madera\", subAdministativeArea: \"\", state: \"CA\", postalCode: \"94925\", country: \"USA\", isoCountryCode: \"us\")], urlAddresses: [], contactRelations: [], socialProfiles: [], instantMessageAddresses: [], phoneNumbers: [Storedge.PhoneNumber(label: \"*$!!$*\", stringValue: \"555-478-7672\"), Storedge.PhoneNumber(label: \"*$!!$*\", stringValue: \"(408) 555-5270\"), Storedge.PhoneNumber(label: \"*$!!$*\", stringValue: \"(408) 555-3514\")], emailAddresses: [Storedge.Email(label: \"*$!!$*\", value: \"d-higgins@mac.com\")]), Storedge.Contact(fullName: \"John  Appleseed\", phones: \"888-555-5512\n888-555-1212\", emails: \"John-Appleseed@mac.com\", imageDataAvailable: false, expanded: false, thumbnailImageData: 0 bytes, imageData: 0 bytes, contactType: 0, identifier: \"410FE041-5C4E-48DA-B4DE-04C15EA3DBAC\", namePrifix: \"\", givenName: \"John\", middleName: \"\", familyName: \"Appleseed\", previousFamilyName: \"\", nameSuffix: \"\", nickName: \"\", organizationName: \"\", departmentName: \"\", jobTitle: \"\", phoneticGivenName: \"\", phoneticMiddleName: \"\", phoneticFamilyName: \"\", phoneticOrganizationName: \"\", note: \"College roommate\", birthday: calendar: gregorian (fixed) year: 1980 month: 6 day: 22 isLeapMonth: false , nonGregorianBirthday: isLeapMonth: false , dates: [], postalAddresses: [Storedge.PostalAddress(label: \"*$!!$*\", street: \"3494 Kuhl Avenue\", subLocality: \"\", city: \"Atlanta\", subAdministativeArea: \"\", state: \"GA\", postalCode: \"30303\", country: \"USA\", isoCountryCode: \"us\"), Storedge.PostalAddress(label: \"*$!!$*\", street: \"1234 Laurel Street\", subLocality: \"\", city: \"Atlanta\", subAdministativeArea: \"\", state: \"GA\", postalCode: \"30303\", country: \"USA\", isoCountryCode: \"us\")], urlAddresses: [], contactRelations: [], socialProfiles: [], instantMessageAddresses: [], phoneNumbers: [Storedge.PhoneNumber(label: \"*$!!$*\", stringValue: \"888-555-5512\"), Storedge.PhoneNumber(label: \"*$!!$*\", stringValue: \"888-555-1212\")], emailAddresses: [Storedge.Email(label: \"*$!!$*\", value: \"John-Appleseed@mac.com\")]), Storedge.Contact(fullName: \"Anna  Haro\", phones: \"555-522-8243\", emails: \"anna-haro@mac.com\", imageDataAvailable: false, expanded: false, thumbnailImageData: 0 bytes, imageData: 0 bytes, contactType: 0, identifier: \"F57C8277-585D-4327-88A6-B5689FF69DFE\", namePrifix: \"\", givenName: \"Anna\", middleName: \"\", familyName: \"Haro\", previousFamilyName: \"\", nameSuffix: \"\", nickName: \"Annie\", organizationName: \"\", departmentName: \"\", jobTitle: \"\", phoneticGivenName: \"\", phoneticMiddleName: \"\", phoneticFamilyName: \"\", phoneticOrganizationName: \"\", note: \"\", birthday: calendar: gregorian (fixed) year: 1985 month: 8 day: 29 isLeapMonth: false , nonGregorianBirthday: isLeapMonth: false , dates: [Storedge.ContactDate(label: \"*$!!$*\", value: calendar: gregorian (fixed) year: 2002 month: 2 day: 15 isLeapMonth: false ), Storedge.ContactDate(label: \"*$!!$*\", value: calendar: gregorian (fixed) year: 2002 month: 2 day: 15 isLeapMonth: false )], postalAddresses: [Storedge.PostalAddress(label: \"*$!!$*\", street: \"1001  Leavenworth Street\", subLocality: \"\", city: \"Sausalito\", subAdministativeArea: \"\", state: \"CA\", postalCode: \"94965\", country: \"USA\", isoCountryCode: \"us\")], urlAddresses: [], contactRelations: [], socialProfiles: [], instantMessageAddresses: [], phoneNumbers: [Storedge.PhoneNumber(label: \"*$!!$*\", stringValue: \"555-522-8243\")], emailAddresses: [Storedge.Email(label: \"*$!!$*\", value: \"anna-haro@mac.com\")]), Storedge.Contact(fullName: \"Hank M. Zakroff\", phones: \"(555) 766-4823\n(707) 555-1854\", emails: \"hank-zakroff@mac.com\", imageDataAvailable: false, expanded: false, thumbnailImageData: 0 bytes, imageData: 0 bytes, contactType: 0, identifier: \"2E73EE73-C03F-4D5F-B1E8-44E85A70F170\", namePrifix: \"\", givenName: \"Hank\", middleName: \"M.\", familyName: \"Zakroff\", previousFamilyName: \"\", nameSuffix: \"\", nickName: \"\", organizationName: \"Financial Services Inc.\", departmentName: \"\", jobTitle: \"Portfolio Manager\", phoneticGivenName: \"\", phoneticMiddleName: \"\", phoneticFamilyName: \"\", phoneticOrganizationName: \"\", note: \"\", birthday: isLeapMonth: false , nonGregorianBirthday: isLeapMonth: false , dates: [], postalAddresses: [Storedge.PostalAddress(label: \"*$!!$*\", street: \"1741 Kearny Street\", subLocality: \"\", city: \"San Rafael\", subAdministativeArea: \"\", state: \"CA\", postalCode: \"94901\", country: \"\", isoCountryCode: \"us\")], urlAddresses: [], contactRelations: [], socialProfiles: [], instantMessageAddresses: [], phoneNumbers: [Storedge.PhoneNumber(label: \"*$!!$*\", stringValue: \"(555) 766-4823\"), Storedge.PhoneNumber(label: \"*$!!$*\", stringValue: \"(707) 555-1854\")], emailAddresses: [Storedge.Email(label: \"*$!!$*\", value: \"hank-zakroff@mac.com\")]), Storedge.Contact(fullName: \"David  Taylor\", phones: \"555-610-6679\", emails: \"\", imageDataAvailable: false, expanded: false, thumbnailImageData: 0 bytes, imageData: 0 bytes, contactType: 0, identifier: \"E94CD15C-7964-4A9B-8AC4-10D7CFB791FD\", namePrifix: \"\", givenName: \"David\", middleName: \"\", familyName: \"Taylor\", previousFamilyName: \"\", nameSuffix: \"\", nickName: \"\", organizationName: \"\", departmentName: \"\", jobTitle: \"\", phoneticGivenName: \"\", phoneticMiddleName: \"\", phoneticFamilyName: \"\", phoneticOrganizationName: \"\", note: \"Plays on Cole\\'s Little League Baseball Team\n\", birthday: calendar: gregorian (fixed) year: 1998 month: 6 day: 15 isLeapMonth: false , nonGregorianBirthday: isLeapMonth: false , dates: [], postalAddresses: [Storedge.PostalAddress(label: \"*$!!$*\", street: \"1747 Steuart Street\", subLocality: \"\", city: \"Tiburon\", subAdministativeArea: \"\", state: \"CA\", postalCode: \"94920\", country: \"USA\", isoCountryCode: \"us\")], urlAddresses: [], contactRelations: [], socialProfiles: [], instantMessageAddresses: [], phoneNumbers: [Storedge.PhoneNumber(label: \"*$!!$*\", stringValue: \"555-610-6679\")], emailAddresses: []), Storedge.Contact(fullName: \"mavya.soni@jayatma.com  \", phones: \"\", emails: \"mavya.soni@jayatma.com\", imageDataAvailable: false, expanded: false, thumbnailImageData: 0 bytes, imageData: 0 bytes, contactType: 0, identifier: \"F01A8F75-B1E0-4B72-A017-6FDE693BE4E4\", namePrifix: \"\", givenName: \"mavya.soni@jayatma.com\", middleName: \"\", familyName: \"\", previousFamilyName: \"\", nameSuffix: \"\", nickName: \"\", organizationName: \"\", departmentName: \"\", jobTitle: \"\", phoneticGivenName: \"\", phoneticMiddleName: \"\", phoneticFamilyName: \"\", phoneticOrganizationName: \"\", note: \"\", birthday: isLeapMonth: false , nonGregorianBirthday: isLeapMonth: false , dates: [], postalAddresses: [], urlAddresses: [], contactRelations: [], socialProfiles: [], instantMessageAddresses: [], phoneNumbers: [], emailAddresses: [Storedge.Email(label: \"*$!!$*\", value: \"mavya.soni@jayatma.com\")]), Storedge.Contact(fullName: \"Dimple  Shah\", phones: \"\", emails: \"\", imageDataAvailable: false, expanded: false, thumbnailImageData: 0 bytes, imageData: 0 bytes, contactType: 0, identifier: \"4B0CE4C4-6569-4936-8C45-34A15725DF9D\", namePrifix: \"\", givenName: \"Dimple\", middleName: \"\", familyName: \"Shah\", previousFamilyName: \"\", nameSuffix: \"\", nickName: \"\", organizationName: \"\", departmentName: \"\", jobTitle: \"\", phoneticGivenName: \"\", phoneticMiddleName: \"\", phoneticFamilyName: \"\", phoneticOrganizationName: \"\", note: \"\", birthday: isLeapMonth: false , nonGregorianBirthday: isLeapMonth: false , dates: [], postalAddresses: [], urlAddresses: [], contactRelations: [], socialProfiles: [], instantMessageAddresses: [], phoneNumbers: [], emailAddresses: []), Storedge.Contact(fullName: \"yash.soni@jayatma.com  \", phones: \"\", emails: \"yash.soni@jayatma.com\", imageDataAvailable: false, expanded: false, thumbnailImageData: 0 bytes, imageData: 0 bytes, contactType: 0, identifier: \"36C2E9A2-3955-49C7-BCED-02CDD1622E69\", namePrifix: \"\", givenName: \"yash.soni@jayatma.com\", middleName: \"\", familyName: \"\", previousFamilyName: \"\", nameSuffix: \"\", nickName: \"\", organizationName: \"\", departmentName: \"\", jobTitle: \"\", phoneticGivenName: \"\", phoneticMiddleName: \"\", phoneticFamilyName: \"\", phoneticOrganizationName: \"\", note: \"\", birthday: isLeapMonth: false , nonGregorianBirthday: isLeapMonth: false , dates: [], postalAddresses: [], urlAddresses: [], contactRelations: [], socialProfiles: [], instantMessageAddresses: [], phoneNumbers: [], emailAddresses: [Storedge.Email(label: \"*$!!$*\", value: \"yash.soni@jayatma.com\")]), Storedge.Contact(fullName: \"Bhavesh  Panchal\", phones: \"\", emails: \"Bhavesh.panchal@jayatma.com\", imageDataAvailable: false, expanded: false, thumbnailImageData: 0 bytes, imageData: 0 bytes, contactType: 0, identifier: \"564EB186-036C-437D-952D-A09A85A21027\", namePrifix: \"\", givenName: \"Bhavesh\", middleName: \"\", familyName: \"Panchal\", previousFamilyName: \"\", nameSuffix: \"\", nickName: \"\", organizationName: \"\", departmentName: \"\", jobTitle: \"\", phoneticGivenName: \"\", phoneticMiddleName: \"\", phoneticFamilyName: \"\", phoneticOrganizationName: \"\", note: \"\", birthday: isLeapMonth: false , nonGregorianBirthday: isLeapMonth: false , dates: [], postalAddresses: [], urlAddresses: [], contactRelations: [], socialProfiles: [], instantMessageAddresses: [], phoneNumbers: [], emailAddresses: [Storedge.Email(label: \"*$!!$*\", value: \"Bhavesh.panchal@jayatma.com\")]), Storedge.Contact(fullName: \"Kayamuddin  Ansari\", phones: \"7575801826\", emails: \"kayamuddin.ansari@jayatma.com\", imageDataAvailable: false, expanded: false, thumbnailImageData: 0 bytes, imageData: 0 bytes, contactType: 0, identifier: \"9D479A76-E092-4C9A-9BCC-418AB1DFC134\", namePrifix: \"\", givenName: \"Kayamuddin\", middleName: \"\", familyName: \"Ansari\", previousFamilyName: \"\", nameSuffix: \"\", nickName: \"\", organizationName: \"\", departmentName: \"\", jobTitle: \"\", phoneticGivenName: \"\", phoneticMiddleName: \"\", phoneticFamilyName: \"\", phoneticOrganizationName: \"\", note: \"\", birthday: isLeapMonth: false , nonGregorianBirthday: isLeapMonth: false , dates: [], postalAddresses: [], urlAddresses: [], contactRelations: [], socialProfiles: [], instantMessageAddresses: [], phoneNumbers: [Storedge.PhoneNumber(label: \"*$!!$*\", stringValue: \"7575801826\")], emailAddresses: [Storedge.Email(label: \"*$!!$*\", value: \"kayamuddin.ansari@jayatma.com\")]), Storedge.Contact(fullName: \"Manan  Bhatt\", phones: \"7575801826\", emails: \"manan.bhatt@jayatma.com\", imageDataAvailable: false, expanded: false, thumbnailImageData: 0 bytes, imageData: 0 bytes, contactType: 0, identifier: \"0C1E052F-6636-4D47-979E-CFF2A66CF505\", namePrifix: \"\", givenName: \"Manan\", middleName: \"\", familyName: \"Bhatt\", previousFamilyName: \"\", nameSuffix: \"\", nickName: \"\", organizationName: \"\", departmentName: \"\", jobTitle: \"\", phoneticGivenName: \"\", phoneticMiddleName: \"\", phoneticFamilyName: \"\", phoneticOrganizationName: \"\", note: \"\", birthday: isLeapMonth: false , nonGregorianBirthday: isLeapMonth: false , dates: [], postalAddresses: [], urlAddresses: [], contactRelations: [], socialProfiles: [], instantMessageAddresses: [], phoneNumbers: [Storedge.PhoneNumber(label: \"*$!!$*\", stringValue: \"7575801826\")], emailAddresses: [Storedge.Email(label: \"*$!!$*\", value: \"manan.bhatt@jayatma.com\")])]"

Comment: Probably there's  a _Attempt to set a non-property-list object_ error?
Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19720674

Comment: @StephanSchlecht Thanks for the quick reply, but I have already checked this post already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your Contact is Codable you could utilize JSONEncoder/JSONDecoder and do the following:

```
if let json = try? JSONEncoder().encode(contact) {
    userDefs?.setValue(json, forKey: "contact");
    ...
```

And to retrieve the Contact again:

```
 if let loaded = userDefs?.value(forKey: "contact") as? Data {
     let contact2 = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Contact.self, from: loaded)
      ...
```

Comment: Okay let me try this

Comment: Thanks, @Stephan Schlecht This works like a charm. And I got the issue what I'm doing wrong.