# Storing Set<CustomObject> to UserDefaults

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, set, userdefaults

I have a custom class which I use as `Set<ListItem>`. I want to store this to userDefaults. However, I'm getting `Attempt to set a non-property-list object as an NSUserDefaults` error when trying to. I tried to change it to `Array` and then save it but still same error. I also tried Saving as data after saw some posts, again this gives me below error.

> NSForwarding: warning: object 0x600003bf9a00 of class 'iTunes_Search_Me.ListItem' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead

```swift
class ListItem: Codable ,Equatable, Hashable {
    let wrapperType, kind: String?
    let artistID, collectionID, trackID: Int?
    let artistName, collectionName, trackName: String?
    let trackViewURL: String?
    let artworkUrl30, artworkUrl60, artworkUrl100: String?
    let releaseDate: String?
    let primaryGenreName: String?
    var isSelected: Bool = false
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case wrapperType, kind
        case artistID
        case collectionID
        case trackID
        case artistName, collectionName, trackName
        case trackViewURL
        case artworkUrl30, artworkUrl60, artworkUrl100, releaseDate, primaryGenreName
    }

    static func ==(lhs: ListItem, rhs: ListItem) -> Bool {
        return lhs.trackID == rhs.trackID
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(trackID)
    }
}
```

[Attempt to set a non-property-list object as an NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720611/attempt-to-set-a-non-property-list-object-as-an-nsuserdefaults)

Comment: Maybe use some kind of database to do this kind of stuff?

Comment: It is a less efficient way to solve it. Ex. CoreData. So storing just an array will be a better option but I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: What I mean is `UserDefaults` is not meant for storing this kind of data. It's meant for things like user preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the model to `UserDefaults` like this:

- Firstly you should create an instance of your model
- And then you can save your model to `UserDefaults`:

  ```
  let encoder = JSONEncoder()
  if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(listItemInstance) {
      let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
      defaults.set(encoded, forKey: "ListItemObject")
  }
  ```

  **You can get model from `UserDefaults` like this**

  ```
  if let savedItem = defaults.object(forKey: "ListItemObject") as? Data {
      let decoder = JSONDecoder()
      if let loadedItem = try? decoder.decode(ListItem.self, from: savedItem) {
          print(loadedItem)
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You could try first setting up saved data:

```
struct saveData{
   static let encoded = "encoded"
}
```

Then save it under that key:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded as! Data, forKey: "encoded")
```

or try saving it as a string instead.