# Load and save struct into UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to save the user in UserDefaults from a struct that fetches the data from an API when a user logs in successfully.

Here is my Webservice class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct Resource<T: Codable> {

    let url : URL
    let httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post
    var body : Data? = nil
}

extension Resource {

    init(url: URL) {
        self.url = url
    }

}



enum HTTPMethod : String {
    case get = "GET"
    case post = "POST"
}

 enum NetworkingError: Error {
        case domainError
        case badResponse
        case encodingError
        case decodingError
    }


class Webservice {

    func load<T>(resource: Resource<T>, caller: UIViewController ,completion: @escaping (Result<T, NetworkingError>) -> Void) {

            var request = URLRequest(url: resource.url)
            request.httpMethod = resource.httpMethod.rawValue
            request.httpBody = resource.body
            request.addValue("application/JSON", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in


                guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                    return completion(.failure(.domainError))
                }

                let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                print(json)

                do {
                let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)

//save to UserDefaults

                    UserDefaults.standard.set(PropertyListEncoder().encode(T), forKey: "user")\\ here I am getting error that T.type does not conform to Encodable protocol.





completion(.success(result))


                }catch {


                    do {

                        if let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode(LoginErrorResponse.self, from: data){
                    print(result.errors.msg)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {

                            let alert = AlertService().alert(message: "\(result.errors.msg[0])")
                            caller.present(alert, animated: true)

                        }
                        completion(.failure(.decodingError))
                    }

                        if let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode(SignUpErrorResponse.self, from: data){
                        print(result.errors.msg)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                                let alert = AlertService().alert(message: "\(result.errors.msg)")
                                caller.present(alert, animated: true)

                            }
                            completion(.failure(.decodingError))
                        }

                }

            }





            }.resume()


        }

    }
```

Here is my model class:

```
import Foundation

struct User: Encodable, Decodable {

    let name: String
    let email: String
    let password: String
    let first_name: String
    let last_name: String
}

extension User {

    static var all : Resource<User> = {

        guard let url = URL(string: "http://orderahead.gagzweblab.xyz:3001/login") else {
                    fatalError("url is incorrect")
               }
        return Resource<User>(url: url)

    }()

    static func create(vm : UserViewModel) -> Resource<UserResponseModel?> {

        let user = User(vm)
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://orderahead.gagzweblab.xyz:3001/register") else {
             fatalError("url is incorrect")
        }
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(user) else {
             fatalError("error encoding user")
        }

        var resource = Resource<UserResponseModel?>(url: url)
        resource.body = data

        return resource
    }

}

extension User {

    init?(_ vm: UserViewModel) {

         let email = vm.email
         let password = vm.password
        let first_name = vm.first_name
        let last_name = vm.last_name
        let name = vm.name

        self.password = password
        self.email = email
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

And here is my view model:

```
import Foundation

struct UserViewModel : Codable {
    let user : User

}

extension UserViewModel {

    var name : String {
        return self.user.name
    }
    var email : String {
        return self.user.email
    }
    var password : String {
        self.user.password
    }
    var first_name: String {
        self.user.first_name
    }
    var last_name: String {
        self.user.last_name
    }

}
```

This is how I am calling it:

```
let login = LoginUser(email: email, password: password)
                   let vm = UserViewModel(loginUser: login)

Webservice().load(resource: User.create(vm: vm), caller: self) { (result) in
```

My model and view model conform to Codable as well as my Resource is Codable too.

What is the reason of the error that `T.type` does not conform to protocol Encodable? How to resolve it?

Is this approach to send and receive data appropriate?

Comment: Maybe this will helps you -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/56920890/7512091

Comment: @emrcftci the error still stays at the encoding line.

Comment: encode `result` instead of `T` -> `.encode(result)` as @VitaliyGozhenko said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify that `T` should be `Encodable` for `load(resource:...` function of class `Webservice:`

Change this:

```
class Webservice {

  func load<T>(resource: Resource<T>, caller: UIViewController ,completion: @escaping (Result<T, NetworkingError>) -> Void) {
```

To this:

```
class Webservice {

  func load<T: Encodable>(resource: Resource<T>, caller: UIViewController ,completion: @escaping (Result<T, NetworkingError>) -> Void) {
```

And also you need to encode value, not generic type here:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(PropertyListEncoder().encode(T.self), forKey: "user")
```

should be

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(try PropertyListEncoder().encode(result), forKey: "user")
```

But another question is: Why do you encode from JSON and then encode it to PropertyList? Why not save JSON data in UserDefaults?

Comment: how will I retrieve the value sir?

Comment: It can be something like this: ```if let userData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "user"),
      let user = try? PropertyListDecoder().decode(User.self, from: user) else {
      //... do something with user
    } else {
      //... user doens't exists
    }```

Answer (score 1):

may be it will work for you.

```
extension UserDefaults {

func save<T: Codable>(_ object: T, forKey key: String) {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    if let encodedObject = try? encoder.encode(object) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedObject, forKey: key)
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
}

func getObject<T: Codable>(forKey key: String) -> T? {
    if let object = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as? Data {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        if let decodedObject = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: object) {
            return decodedObject
        }
    }
    return nil
}}
```

this is how to store

```
func setCoableInUser<T: Codable>(_ object:T, key: String)-> Void{
UserDefaults.standard.save(object, forKey: key)}
```

Comment: looks like for some reason primitive types can be saved with this as well, but only in ios13 forward.